# bash regex with quotes?

Tags: regex, bash, quotes

The following code

```
number=1
if [[ $number =~ [0-9] ]]
then
  echo matched
fi
```

works. If I try to use quotes in the regex, however, it stops:

```
number=1
if [[ $number =~ "[0-9]" ]]
then
  echo matched
fi
```

I tried `"\[0-9\]"`, too. What am I missing?

Funnily enough, [bash advanced scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#REGEXMATCHREF) suggests this should work.

Bash version 3.2.39.

Comment: The ABS is rather notorious as a source for inaccurate (or, on better days, merely misleading) guidance; consider it the W3Schools of shell scripting. Consider the bash-hackers.org or wooledge wikis as alternatives maintained with an eye to accuracy.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It was changed [between 3.1 and 3.2](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS). Guess the advanced guide needs an update.

> This is a terse description of the new
>   features added to bash-3.2 since the
>   release of bash-3.1.  As always, the
>   manual page (doc/bash.1) is the place
>   to look for complete descriptions.
>
> 1. New Features in Bash
>
> snip
>
> f.  Quoting the string argument to the
>   [[ command's  =~ operator now forces
>       string matching, as with the other pattern-matching operators.

Sadly this'll break existing quote using scripts unless you had the insight to store patterns in variables and use them instead of the regexes directly. Example below.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ number=2
$ if [[ $number =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo match; fi
$ if [[ $number =~ [0-9] ]]; then echo match; fi
match
$ re="[0-9]"
$ if [[ $number =~ $re ]]; then echo MATCH; fi
MATCH

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.0(1)-release (i586-suse-linux)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ number=2
$ if [[ $number =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo match; fi
match
$ if [[ "$number" =~ [0-9] ]]; then echo match; fi
match
```

Comment: This is real fun. Quoted regexes no longer work. Unquoted regexes with spaces don't work. Variable based regexes work even if they include spaces. What a mess.

Comment: Interestingly, this works: `if [[ $number =~ ["0-9"] ]]; then echo match; fi`

Comment: This is so disappointing that we need to rely on `echo` or `compat31` workarounds...

Answer (score 23):

Bash 3.2 introduced a compatibility option compat31 which reverts bash regular expression quoting behavior back to 3.1

**Without compat31:**

```
$ shopt -u compat31
$ shopt compat31
compat31        off
$ set -x
$ if [[ "9" =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo match; else echo no match; fi
+ [[ 9 =~ \[0-9] ]]
+ echo no match
no match
```

**With compat31:**

```
$ shopt -s compat31
+ shopt -s compat31
$ if [[ "9" =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo match; else echo no match; fi
+ [[ 9 =~ [0-9] ]]
+ echo match
match
```

Link to patch:
http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.2-patches/bash32-039

Answer (score 9):

GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Some examples of string match and regex match

```
    $ if [[ 234 =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match
    $ 

    $ if [[ 234 =~ [0-9] ]]; then echo matches;  fi # regex natch 
    matches


    $ var="[0-9]"

    $ if [[ 234 =~ $var ]]; then echo matches;  fi # regex match
    matches


    $ if [[ 234 =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match after substituting $var as [0-9]

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi   # string match after substituting $var as [0-9]

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ $var ]]; then echo matches;  fi # regex match after substituting $var as [0-9]
    matches


    $ if [[ "rss\$var919" =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match won't work

    $ if [[ "rss\\$var919" =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match won't work


    $ if [[ "rss'$var'""919" =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # $var is substituted on LHS & RHS and then string match happens 
    matches

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ "\$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match !
    matches



    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match failed
    $ 

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ '$var' ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match
    matches



    $ echo $var
    [0-9]

    $ 

    $ if [[ abc123def =~ "[0-9]" ]]; then echo matches;  fi

    $ if [[ abc123def =~ [0-9] ]]; then echo matches;  fi
    matches

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ '$var' ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match due to single quotes on RHS $var matches $var
    matches


    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ $var ]]; then echo matches;  fi # Regex match 
    matches
    $ if [[ 'rss$var' =~ $var ]]; then echo matches;  fi # Above e.g. really is regex match and not string match
    $


    $ if [[ 'rss$var919[0-9]' =~ "$var" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match RHS substituted and then matched
    matches

    $ if [[ 'rss$var919' =~ "'$var'" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # trying to string match '$var' fails


    $ if [[ '$var' =~ "'$var'" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # string match still fails as single quotes are omitted on RHS 

    $ if [[ \'$var\' =~ "'$var'" ]]; then echo matches;  fi # this string match works as single quotes are included now on RHS
    matches
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in other answers, putting the regular expression in a variable is a general way to achieve compatibility over different [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) versions.  You may also use this workaround to achieve the same thing, while keeping your regular expression within the conditional expression:

```
$ number=1
$ if [[ $number =~ $(echo "[0-9]") ]]; then echo matched; fi
matched
$
```

Comment: Using a command substitution incurs a small performance penalty, which might be significant in some cases (e.g., doing a large number of checks in a loop).

Answer (score 2):

Using a local variable has slightly better performance than using command substitution.

For larger scripts, or collections of scripts, it might make sense to use a utility to prevent unwanted local variables polluting the code, and to reduce verbosity. This seems to work well:

```bash
# Bash's built-in regular expression matching requires the regular expression
# to be unqouted (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/218156), which makes it harder
# to use some special characters, e.g., the dollar sign.
# This wrapper works around the issue by using a local variable, which means the
# quotes are not passed on to the regex engine.
regex_match() {
  local string regex
  string="${1?}"
  regex="${2?}"
  # shellcheck disable=SC2046 `regex` is deliberately unquoted, see above.
  [[ "${string}" =~ ${regex} ]]
}
```

Example usage:

```bash
if regex_match "${number}" '[0-9]'; then
  echo matched
fi
```