# How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-statements

I want to check if a variable has a valid year using a regular expression. Reading the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) I understand I could use the operator =~

Looking at the example below, I would expect to see "not OK" but I see "OK". What am I doing wrong?

```
i="test"
if [ $i=~"200[78]" ]
then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "not OK"
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash regex with quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

Comment: Note this was failing because of the lack of spaces around `=~`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It was changed between 3.1 and 3.2:

> This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-3.2 since the release of bash-3.1.
>
> Quoting the string argument to the [[ command's  =~ operator now forces string matching, as with the other pattern-matching operators.

So use it without the quotes thus:

```
i="test"
if [[ $i =~ 200[78] ]] ; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "not OK"
fi
```

Comment: How do i handle the situation when the regex contains spaces if I cannot quote? If the regex is e.g. `a +b` it will report a syntax error...

Comment: @Alderath: Use `a\ \+b` to escape the space and the plus character.

Answer (score 8):

You need spaces around the operator =~

```
i="test"
if [[ $i =~ "200[78]" ]];
then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "not OK"
fi
```

Comment: paxdiablo's answer is right, adding spaces here does not help (you now also get "not OK" for 2008, the only string that gets matched is literally "200[78]").