# Regex matching in if not working

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts)

Why isn't this working?

```
if [[ "foo" =~ "[f][o][o]" || "foo" =~ "(foo)" || "foo" =~ ".*" ]]
then
    echo "Success"
else
   echo "Fail"
fi
# Result: Fail
# Expected: Success

if [[ "foo" =~ "foo" ]]
then
    echo "Success"
else
   echo "Fail"
fi
# Result: Success
# Expected: Success
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the quotes from each regex:

```
if [[ "foo" =~ [f][o][o] || "foo" =~ (foo) || "foo" =~ .* ]]
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Fail"
fi
```

Apparently, the quotes force the regex to be interpreted as a literal string.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm using [[ "$testval" =~ Failed: [1-9] ]]