# Bash - Extract numbers from String

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I got a string which looks like this:

"abcderwer 123123  10,200 asdfasdf iopjjop"

Now I want to extract numbers, following the scheme xx,xxx where x is a number between 0-9. E.g. 10,200. Has to be five digit, and has to contain ",".

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You can use `grep`:

```
$ echo "abcderwer 123123 10,200 asdfasdf iopjjop" | egrep -o '[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}'
10,200
```

Answer (score 5):

In pure Bash:

```
pattern='([[:digit:]]{2},[[:digit:]]{3})'
[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out pattern matching and regular expressions.

Links:

[Bash regular expressions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions)

[Patterns and pattern matching](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern)

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts)

and as mentioned above, one way to utilize pattern matching is with grep. 
Other uses: echo supports patterns (globbing) and find supports regular expressions.

Comment: `echo` does not and `find` is not applicable to the question.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I never said they were. And you can use patterns with echo. Example: echo *ocu?ent? would return "Documents" if you're in a regular home folder. I realize you meant regex though, I'll edit that :)

Comment: That's not a regex, that's globbing.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson which is pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Simple pattern matching (glob patterns) is built into the shell.  Assuming you have the strings in `$*` (that is, they are command-line arguments to your script, or you have used `set` on a string you have obtained otherwise), try this:

```
for token; do
  case $token in
    [0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9] ) echo "$token" ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: That would be `$@`. There's a difference.

Comment: When you access the command line, there certainly is a difference between `$*` and `$@`; but I specifically chose to call the variable which contains the `argv` array by its original Bourne name because that's the name many beginner-level expositions use; and in this context, when you want the values split into whitespace-separated tokens, that's what a script would use.  I agree that if you have to refer to the positional parameters directly in a script, `"$@"` is almost always what you want.

Comment: With, for example, `set -- 'abc def' ghi`, `for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done` does the right thing. These rarely do the right thing: `$*` or `"$*"` (rarely = only when you want to flatten the arguments). There's no point in continuing to repeat beginner-level expositions which are wrong.

Comment: `for token; do` does the right thing here, regardless of how you got the things in there; what's to argue about?

Answer (score 0):

The following example using your input data string should solve the problem using sed.

```
$ echo abcderwer 123123 10,200 asdfasdf iopjjop | sed -ne 's/^.*\([0-9,]\{6\}\).*$/\1/p'
10,200
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly non-typical solution:

```
< input tr -cd [0-9,\ ] | tr \  '\012' | grep '^..,...$'
```

(The first tr removes everything except commas, spaces, and digits.  The
second tr replaces spaces with newlines, putting each "number" on a separate
line, and the grep discards everything except those that match your criterion.)