# bash extended regex operators

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to use the extended regex operators available in bash (?, *, +, @, !). The manual says I just have to enclose with parentheses a list of patterns, then use the operator before the left bracket. So if I want a pattern of zero or more a's:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ *(a) ]]
then
   echo $1
fi
```

but this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly in the docs does it say the operator must go before the group? That's not the case in any regex engine I know, and it's not for bash either. (Even if it was, "zero or more a's" matches any string.)

Comment: This looks like a dupe of [How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts)

Comment: Here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per `man bash`:

> An  additional  binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the same
>   precedence as  `==` and `!=`.  When it is used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is  considered an extended regular expression  and
>   matched  accordingly  (as  in  [regex(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html)).  The return value is 0 if
>   the string matches the pattern, and 1  otherwise.  If the regular
>   expression is syntactically incorrect,  the   conditional 
>   expression's  return  value  is  2.   If the shell option  `nocasematch`
>   is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of 
>   alphabetic characters.  Any part of the pattern  may  be  quoted  to
>   force it  to be matched as a string.  Substrings matched by
>   parenthesized subexpressions  within the regular expression are saved
>   in the array variable `BASH_REMATCH`.   The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with
>   index  0  is  the  portion  of  the string  matching the entire
>   regular expression.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index  *n* is the
>   portion of the string matching the *n*th  parenthesized  subexpression.

I quoted the whole thing here because I think it's useful to know. You use standard POSIX extended regular expressions on the right hand side.

In particular, the expression on the right side may match a substring of the left operand. Thus, to match the whole string, use `^` and `$` anchors:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^a*$ ]]
then
    echo $1
fi
```

Comment: I get it now. The parentheses are used in the case where you are not using the =~ operator.

Comment: Right. So if you do `shopt -s extglob`, you can do `ls *(a)` to list all files that consist of `a`s.