# How to check whether a string has at least one alphabetic character?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to check whether a string has at least one 
alphabetic character?
a regex could be like:

```
"^.*[a-zA-Z].*$"
```

however, I want to judge whether a string  has at least one 
alphabetic character?
so I want to use, like

```
 if [ it contains at least one alphabetic character];then
 ...
 else
 ...
 fi
```

so I'm at a loss on how to use the regex

I tried

```
if [ "$x"=~[a-zA-Z]+ ];then echo "yes"; else echo "no" ;fi
or
if [ "$x"=~"^.*[a-zA-Z].*$" ];then echo "yes"; else echo "no" ;fi
```

and test with x="1234", both of the above script output result of "yes", so they are wrong

how to achieve my goal?thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts).

Comment: There are two problems: you need to use `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`; and you need to have spaces around the `=~` operator, otherwise bash sees it as part of one single long string.

Comment: @Anders Johansson, you are right, it is ok  now, but why do I need double [], can you explain this a bit? thanks!

Comment: @user1944267, the `[` builtin (see `man [`) is much less powerful than `[[` (see `man bash`; for example `[[` supports more operators and natural constructs like `&&` and `||` with their usual meaning while `[` requires `-a` and `-o` with explicit parentheses to get the same result). The `=~` operator only exists in `[[`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

x="1234"
y="a1234"

if [[ "$x" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; then
        echo "$x has one alphabet"
fi

if [[ "$y" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; then
        echo "Y is $y and has at least one alphabet"
fi
```

Comment: I deleted 0-9, coz I only check ALPHABETIC characters. but the output is not as expected

Comment: @user1944267, this solution should work, and is preferrable since it works within bash instead of calling a separate tool. If the output is not as expected, please post your input data and expected output so we can help. (@abhi.gupta200297, the `+` is not needed).

Comment: Actually this won't work, you need to use `[[` and `]]` for regex in bash.

Comment: Ok i edited the code for a better example. @Anders thanks for pointing out. I corrected the brackets for regex.

Comment: @user1944267 I think your problem is no spaces between tokens.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be portable, I'd call `/usr/bin/grep` with `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[:alpha:]` character class that respects your locale, with a regular expression

```
[[ $str =~ [[:alpha:]] ]] && echo has alphabetic char
```

or a glob-style pattern

```
[[ $str == *[[:alpha:]]* ]] && echo has alphabetic char
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common in **sh** scripts to use **grep** in an **if** clause. You can find many such examples in /etc/rc.d/.

```
if echo $theinputstring | grep -q '[a-zA-Z]' ; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```