# Check input consists only of numeric characters in shell script

Tags: shell

I need to check that the input consists only of numeric characters. I have the code below, but it didn't work properly.

```
if [[ $1 =~ [0-9] ]]; then
echo "Invalid input"
fi
```

It should give true only for 678686 not for yy66666.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BASH: Test whether string is valid as an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210349/bash-test-whether-string-is-valid-as-an-integer)

Comment: The reverse test is often more concise: `[[ $1 =~ [^[:digit:]] ]] && echo Invalid` -- if you find one non-digit, it's invalid

Answer (score 3):

How about this:-

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $Number =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Invalid input" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

or

```
case $Number in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) echo nonnumeric;;
    *) echo numeric;;
esac
```

Comment: @tripleee:- Thanks a lot!!! Sometimes you get silly things done just to get an upvote!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using start/end anchors with your pattern. If you don't, the match succeeds with a part of a test string. Don't forget that you have to use a pattern matching the complete test string if you follow this suggestion.

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
echo "Invalid input"
fi
```

Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts) for more details.

Comment: @jcrshankar:- Although the above solution works well. I have posted another option as well!!! Have a look :)