# Bash regex test working the opposite way?

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have written a small bash script to check machine's architecture:

```
#!/bin/bash

v=$(uname -m)
echo $v

if [[ $v  =~ ".*64.*" ]] ; then
  echo "64 bits!"
else 
  echo "32 bits!"
fi
```

being launch on my machine:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

So why do I get this result ?

```
$ ./test.sh
x86_64
32 bits!
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts)

Comment: @adback03 This helped. I needed to remove the parenthesis from around the string.

Answer (score 3):

It works if you take out the quotes.

```
if [[ $v  =~ .*64.* ]] ; then
```

Bash is picky with the regex support; things like quoting have significant and sometimes unexpected consequences. [It has also changed between Bash versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

The portable way to write that if you don't need full regex support is

```
case $v in *64*) echo 64 bits ;; *) echo 32 bits;; esac
```

This is portable all the way back to the original v7 Bourne shell.

Comment: If you do need to use a regular expression, it's usually better to assign it to a variable first (`regex='.*64.*'`) then expand the variable in the conditional command (`[[ $v =~ $regex ]]`).