# How to get only the value of a particular index of an array using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

In the below mentioned code i need to only get the value of access token and write it to another file.

```
{
  "access_token": "dddddddddddddd",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata 
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: "below-mentioned code" that's not bash code.

Comment: And that's not an array.

Comment: Do you want to *parse a string* with the above-mentioned contents?

Comment: i need the value of only access token and write that content to another file using shellscipt

Comment: Hi Shilpa, welcome to stackoverflow. Its important to be detailed in your questions here so that people can help you easily and you need to show what you tried and where you stumbled.

Comment: You look to have json posted in your question. Do not manipulate json with bash. Instead use a tool that can validate json, like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Perfect example, you are missing the `",` following `"metadata`. With valid json, (stored in `file`) you only need `jq .access_token file` to retrieve `"dddddddddddddd"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s='{"access_token": "dddddddddddddd", "expires_in": 3600, "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata "token_type": "Bearer"}'
echo ${s:18:14} # prints dddddddddddddd
```

Or use [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts).