# bash script for regular expression Err: [1-9]

Tags: regex, bash

I'm sure this is a small thing, but I'm relatively new to bash and regular expressions,

given a string `summary =    689 in     2s =  350.3/s Avg:     4 Min:     0 Max:    84 Err:    24 (3.48%)` I want to check if the text `Err: [1-9]` occurs in the given string in a bash script.  In order to achieve that I have written the following script

```
digit="Err: 8"

if [[ $digit =~ 'Err: [1-9]' ]]; 
then
    echo "$digit is a digit"
else
    echo "oops"
fi
```

However this does not work, it will goes into the false.  When I tested the regular expression with an online tool it seem to work fine, I'm not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: Put your regex pattern in a variable and then use that variable in if statament.

Comment: The `[1-9]` part is in quotes, so it's treated as a literal string rather than a pattern. You can use use `'Err: '[1-9]` or `Err:\ [1-9]` or put the pattern in a variable as Alireza said (and then don't put quotes around the variable when you use it). See: [How do I use regular expressions in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304864/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-bash-scripts) BTW, you don't really need full regex here, you could just use a glob (aka wildcard) pattern: `if [[ "$digit" = *'Err: '[1-9]* ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your regex pattern in a variable and use that variable in if statement like this:

```
digit="Err: 8"
pattern="Err: [1-9]"
if [[ $digit =~ $pattern ]]; 
then
    echo "$digit is a digit"
else
    echo "oops"
fi
```

or if you don't want to use an additional variable you can change your if statement like this:

```
digit="Err: 8"
if [[ $digit =~ Err:\ [1-9] ]]; 
then
    echo "$digit is a digit"
else
    echo "oops"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[[:blank:]]` to match spaces and tabs without the surrounding quotes:

```
if [[ $digit =~ Err:[[:blank:]][1-9] ]];
```

Or you can escape the space:

```
if [[ $digit =~ Err:\ [1-9] ]];
```

Or put the pattern with quotes in a variable:

```
pattern='Err: [1-9]'
if [[ $digit =~ $pattern ]];
```

As the first example string seems to have multiple spaces, you could repeat the character class:

```
digit="summary =    689 in     2s =  350.3/s Avg:     4 Min:     0 Max:    84 Err:    24 (3.48%)"
pattern='Err: [1-9]'
if [[ $digit =~ Err:[[:blank:]]+[1-9] ]];
then
    echo "$digit is a digit"
else
    echo "oops"
fi
```

Output

```
summary =    689 in     2s =  350.3/s Avg:     4 Min:     0 Max:    84 Err:    24 (3.48%) is a digit
```