# Return a regex match in a Bash script, instead of replacing it

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, sh

I just want to match some text in a Bash script. I've tried using sed but I can't seem to make it just output the match instead of replacing it with something.

```
echo -E "TestT100String" | sed 's/[0-9]+/dontReplace/g'
```

Which will output `TestTdontReplaceString`.

Which isn't what I want, I want it to output `100`.

Ideally, it would put all the matches in an array.

edit:

Text input is coming in as a string:

```
newName()
{
 #Get input from function
 newNameTXT="$1"

 if [[ $newNameTXT ]]; then
 #Use code that im working on now, using the $newNameTXT string.

 fi
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
echo "TestT100String" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'

echo "TestT100String" | grep -o  '[0-9]\+'
```

The method you use to put the results in an array depends somewhat on how the actual data is being retrieved. There's not enough information in your question to be able to guide you well. However, here is one method:

```
index=0
while read -r line
do
    array[index++]=$(echo "$line" | grep -o  '[0-9]\+')
done < filename
```

Here's another way:

```
array=($(grep -o '[0-9]\+' filename))
```

Comment: Added in the input method in the original question. (it’s input is in the forum of a string)

Answer (score 58):

You could do this purely in bash using the double square bracket `[[ ]]` test operator, which stores results in an array called `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
[[ "TestT100String" =~ ([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: it takes a real monkey to figure this out

Comment: But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes for issues with bash quoting in different BASH versions.

Answer (score 31):

Pure **Bash**. Use parameter substitution (no external processes and pipes):

```
string="TestT100String"

echo ${string//[^[:digit:]]/}
```

Removes all non-digits.

Answer (score 9):

I Know this is an old topic but I came her along same searches and found another great possibility apply a regex on a String/Variable using grep:

```
# Simple
$(echo "TestT100String" | grep -Po "[0-9]{3}")
# More complex using lookaround
$(echo "TestT100String" | grep -Po "(?i)TestT\K[0-9]{3}(?=String)")
```

With using lookaround capabilities search expressions can be extended for better matching. Where `(?i)` indicates the Pattern before the searched Pattern (lookahead),
`\K` indicates the actual search pattern and `(?=)` contains the pattern after the search (lookbehind).

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

The given example matches the same as the PCRE regex `TestT([0-9]{3})String`

Comment: Wow, can't believe people still come here, after 10 years. I would never have guessed it would be viewed this much when I was asking it. I thought I was the only one at the time, who didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Bash is so terrible that there are people looking to do things like this all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Use grep. Sed is an editor. If you only want to match a regexp, grep is more than sufficient.

Comment: SED doesn't write to the source file - only way for that to happen is if you write the output with the same filename in order to overwrite the file.

Comment: True, but sed is still an editor. Its name is even short for stream editor. If he only needs to match he can use grep.

Comment: i don't think he wants to match. He says he needs the 100

Comment: so using grep's -o should do the job

Comment: Yep, I need the 100, working solution found though, thanks to your guys (especially Dennis)

Comment: I agree, only it should be said: SED is more than sufficient, while grep IS sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
linux$ echo -E "TestT100String" | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"")}1'
100
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why nobody ever uses `expr`: it's portable and easy.

```
newName()
{
 #Get input from function
 newNameTXT="$1"

 if num=`expr "$newNameTXT" : '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\)'`; then
  echo "contains $num"
 fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , the Sed with the s/"pattern1"/"pattern2"/g  just replaces globally all the pattern1s to pattern 2.

Besides that, sed while by default print the entire line by default .
I suggest piping the instruction to a cut command and trying to extract the numbers u want :

If u are lookin only to use sed then use TRE:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(0-9\)\(0-9\)\(0-9\).*/\1,\2,\3/g'.
```

I dint try and execute the above command so just make sure the syntax is right.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

using just the bash shell

```
declare -a array
i=0
while read -r line
do
        case "$line" in
            *TestT*String* )
            while true
            do
                line=${line#*TestT}
                array[$i]=${line%%String*}
                line=${line#*String*}
                i=$((i+1))
                case "$line" in
                    *TestT*String* ) continue;;
                    *) break;;
                esac
            done
            esac
done <"file"
echo ${array[@]}
```