# How extract json value using only pure bash?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

No `jq`, no `grep -Po`, even no `awk`.
**Only `bash`**.

**Goal: simulate `grep -Po '(?<="code":")\w+(?=")'` on bash.**

*It's extraction of code value from json.*

Json example:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "createdBy":"admin",
      "createdDate":"2019-04-01T07:07:37+0000",
      "lastModifiedBy":"admin",
      "lastModifiedDate":"2019-04-01T07:07:37+0000",
      "code":"ABC123"
    }
  ],
  "first": true,
  "last": true,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 1,
  "numberOfElements": 1,
  "size": 10,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null
}
```

Expecting result: `ABC123`.

---

My attempt:

```
CODE='{
  "content": [
    {
      "createdBy":"admin",
      "createdDate":"2019-04-01T07:07:37+0000",
      "lastModifiedBy":"admin",
      "lastModifiedDate":"2019-04-01T07:07:37+0000",
      "code":"ABC123"
    }
  ],
  "first": true,
  "last": true,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 1,
  "numberOfElements": 1,
  "size": 10,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null
}'
echo "${CODE//[code":"\w+]/}"
```

It replaces, but I want substring... 
*It was a try to use smth like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916293/4386227*

Comment: See https://ideone.com/vHzPiM if you just want a single match. Why haven't you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898573/3832970?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's my bad, ty.