# Does bash support word boundary regular expressions?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to match on the presence of a word in a list before adding that word again (to avoid duplicates). I am using bash 4.2.24 and am trying the below:

```
[[  $foo =~ \bmyword\b ]]
```

also

```
[[  $foo =~ \<myword\> ]]
```

However, neither seem to work. They are mentioned in the bash docs example: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html.

I presume I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what.

Comment: As an aside: the behavior of bash's `=~` operator is _platform-dependent_, because the host platform's regex libraries are used. Thus, for instance, even with the workaround in the accepted answer, `\b` and `\<` / `\>` won't work on BSD-like systems such as OSX. Conversely, OSX supports `[[:\<:]]` and `[[:\>:]]`, which won't work on Linux.

Comment: Use double backslashes (\\) for regex for example in `[ string =~ pattern]` or in `grep`

Comment: There are two topics discussed in the answers here. The first is the use of a regex literal, and the second is platform-dependence of word boundary tokens. For the first topic, there's a more focused discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/218156.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, all the listed regex extensions are supported but you'll have better luck putting the pattern in a variable before using it. Try this:

```
re=\\bmyword\\b
[[ $foo =~ $re ]]
```

Digging around I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes), whose answers seems to explain why the behaviour changes when the regex is written inline as in your example.

<sup>**Editor's note**: The linked question does *not* explain the OP's problem; it merely explains how starting with Bash version 3.2 regexes (or at least the special regex chars.) must by default be *unquoted* to be treated as such - which is exactly what the OP attempted.

However, the workarounds in this answer *are* effective.</sup>

You'll probably have to rewrite your tests so as to use a temporary variable for your regexes, or use the 3.1 compatibility mode:

```
shopt -s compat31
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you can use command substitution: `[[ $foo =~ $(echo '\<myword\>') ]]`. It's still annoyingly verbose, but at least doesn't require a stray variable.

Comment: Note that the `$(echo ..)` version comes with a performance penalty, as compared to the local variable, which might be a disadvantage in some cases.

Answer (score 70):

**tl;dr**

- To be safe, **do not use a regex *literal* with `=~`**.
  Instead, use:

  - *either*: an **auxiliary variable** - see [@Eduardo Ivancec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9793094/45375).
  - *or*: **a command substitution that outputs a string literal** - see [@ruakh's comment on @Eduardo Ivancec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9792702/45375#comment-12473988)
  - Note that both **must be used *unquoted*** as the `=~` RHS.
- **Whether `\b` and `\<` / `\>` are *supported at all* depends on the *host platform*, not Bash**:

  - they DO work on *Linux*,
  - but NOT on *BSD*-based platforms such as **macOS**; there, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` instead, which, in the context of an unquoted regex *literal*, must be escaped as **`[[:\<:]]` and `[[:\>:]]`**; the following works as expected, but only on BSD/macOS:

    - `[[ ' myword ' =~ [[:\<:]]myword[[:\>:]] ]] && echo YES # OK`
- The **problem wouldn't arise** - on any platform - **if you limited your regex to the constructs in the [POSIX ERE (extended regular expression) specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)**.

  - Unfortunately, POSIX EREs do *not* support word-boundary assertions, though you can *emulate* them - see the last section.
  - As on macOS, *no* `\`-prefixed constructs are supported, so that handy character-class shortcuts such as `\s` and `\w` aren't available either.
  - However, the up-side is that such **ERE-compliant regexes** are then ***portable*** (work on both Linux and macOS, for instance)

`=~` is the rare case (the only case?) of a *built-in* Bash feature whose behavior is *platform-dependent*: It uses the regex libraries of the platform it is running on, resulting in *different regex flavors on different platforms*.

Thus, it is **generally non-trivial and requires extra care to write *portable* code that uses the `=~` operator**. 
**Sticking with POSIX EREs is the only robust approach**, which means that you have to work around their limitations - see bottom section.

If you want to know more, read on.

---

On Bash v3.2+ (unless the `compat31` `shopt` option is set), **the RHS (right-hand side operand) of the `=~` operator must be *unquoted* in order to be recognized as a *regex*** (*if you quote* the right operand, `=~` performs regular *string comparison* instead).

<sup>More accurately, at least the *special regex characters and sequences must be unquoted*, so it's OK and useful to quote those *substrings* that should be taken *literally*; e.g., `[[ '*' =~ ^'*' ]]` matches, because `^` is *unquoted* and thus correctly recognized as the start-of-string anchor, whereas `*`, which is normally a special regex char, matches *literally* due to the quoting.</sup>

However, there appears to be a **design limitation** in (at least) `bash 3.x` that **prevents use of `\`-prefixed regex constructs (e.g., `\<`, `\>`, `\b`, `\s`, `\w`, ...) in a *literal* `=~` RHS**; the limitation **affects *Linux***, whereas BSD/macOS versions are *not* affected, due to fundamentally not supporting any `\`-prefixed regex constructs:

```
# Linux only:
# PROBLEM (see details further below): 
#   Seen by the regex engine as: <word>
#   The shell eats the '\' before the regex engine sees them.
[[ ' word ' =~ \<word\> ]] && echo MATCHES # !! DOES NOT MATCH
#   Causes syntax error, because the shell considers the < unquoted.
#   If you used \\bword\\b, the regex engine would see that as-is.
[[ ' word ' =~ \\<word\\> ]] && echo MATCHES # !! BREAKS
#   Using the usual quoting rules doesn't work either:
#   Seen by the regex engine as: \\<word\\> instead of \<word\>
[[ ' word ' =~ \\\<word\\\> ]] && echo MATCHES # !! DOES NOT MATCH

# WORKAROUNDS
  # Aux. viarable.  
re='\<word\>'; [[ ' word ' =~ $re ]] && echo MATCHES # OK
  # Command substitution
[[ ' word ' =~ $(printf %s '\<word\>') ]] && echo MATCHES # OK

  # Change option compat31, which then allows use of '...' as the RHS
  # CAVEAT: Stays in effect until you reset it, may have other side effects.
  #         Using (...) around  the command confines the effect to a subshell.
(shopt -s compat31; [[ ' word ' =~ '\<word\>' ]] && echo MATCHES) # OK
```

---

**The problem:**

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Fólkvangr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9657437/f%c3%b3lkvangr) for his input.</sup>

**A *literal* RHS of `=~` is by design parsed *differently*** than unquoted tokens as arguments, in an **attempt to allow the user to focus on escaping characters *just* for the *regex***, without also having to worry about the usual *shell* escaping rules in unquoted tokens.

For instance,

```
[[ 'a[b' =~ a\[b ]] && echo MATCHES  # OK
```

matches, because the `\` is _passed through to the regex engine (that is, the regex engine too sees *literal* `a\[b`), whereas if you used the same unquoted token as a regular argument, the usual [*shell expansions*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) applied to unquoted tokens would "eat" the `\`, because it is interpreted as a *shell* escape character:

```
$ printf %s a\[b
a[b  # '\' was removed by the shell.
```

However, **in the context of `=~` this exceptional passing through of `\` is only applied before characters that are *regex* metacharacters *by themselves***, as defined by the [ERE (extended regular expressions) POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) (in order to escape them *for the regex*, so that they're treated as *literals*:
`\ ^ $ [ {  . ? * + ( ) |`
**Conversely, these regex metacharacters may exceptionally be used *unquoted*** - and indeed *must* be left unquoted to have their special *regex* meaning - even though most of them normally require `\`-escaping in unquoted tokens to prevent the *shell* from interpreting them.
Yet, a ***subset* of the *shell* metacharacters *do* still need escaping, for the *shell*'s sake**, so as not to break the syntax of the `[[ ... ]]` conditional:
`& ; < > space`
Since these characters aren't also *regex* metacharacters, there is no need to also support escaping them on the regex side, so that, for instance, the regex engine seeing `\&` in the RHS as just `&` works fine.

**For any *other* character preceded by `\`, the shell *removes* the `\`** before sending the string to the regex engine (as it does during normal shell expansion), which is unfortunate, because then **even characters that the shell *doesn't* consider special cannot be passed as `\<char>`** to the regex engine, because the shell invariably passes them as just `<char>`.
E.g, `\b` is invariably seen as just `b` by the regex engine.

**It is therefore currently impossible to use a (by definition non-POSIX) regex construct in the form `\<char>` (e.g., `\<`, `\>`, `\b`, `\s`, `\w`, `\d`, ...) in a literal, unquoted `=~` RHS**, because **no form of escaping can ensure that these constructs are seen by the *regex* engine as such**, after parsing by the *shell*:

Since neither `<`, `>`, nor `b` are *regex* metacharacters, the shell *removes* the `\` from `\<`, `\>`, `\b` (as happens in regular shell expansion). Therefore, passing `\<word\>`, for instance, makes the regex engine see `<word>`, which is not the intent:

- `[[ '<word>' =~ \<word\> ]] && echo YES` matches, because the regex engine sees `<word>`.
- `[[ 'boo' =~ ^\boo ]] && echo YES` matches, because the regex engine sees `^boo`.

Trying `\\<word\\>` *breaks* the command, because the *shell* treats each `\\` as an escaped `\`, which means that metacharacter `<` is then considered *unquoted*, causing a *syntax error*:

- `[[ ' word ' =~ \\<word\\> ]] && echo YES` causes a syntax error.
- This wouldn't happen with `\\b`, but `\\b` is *passed through* (due to the `\` preceding a regex metachar, `\`), which also doesn't work:

  - `[[ '\boo' =~ ^\\boo ]] && echo YES` matches, because the regex engine sees `\\boo`, which matches literal `\boo`.

Trying `\\\<word\\\>` - which by *normal* shell expansion rules results in `\<word\>` (try `printf %s \\\<word\\\>`) - *also* doesn't work:

- What happens is that the shell *eats* the `\` in `\<` (ditto for `\b` and other `\`-prefixed sequences), and then passes the preceding `\\` through to the regex engine *as-is* (again, because `\` is preserved before a *regex* metachar):
- `[[ ' \<word\> ' =~ \\\<word\\\> ]] && echo YES` matches, because the regex engine sees `\\<word\\>`, which matches literal `\<word\>`.

In short:

- Bash's parsing of `=~` RHS *literals* was designed with *single-character* regex metacharacters in mind, and does not support *multi-character* constructs that start with `\`, such as `\<`.

  - Because POSIX EREs support no such constructs, `=~` works as designed if you limit yourself to such regexes.
  - However, even within this constraint the design is somewhat awkward, due to the need to mix regex-related and shell-related `\`-escaping (quoting).
  - Fólkvangr found the official design rationale in the Bash FAQ [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/FAQ#n1927), which, however, neither addresses said awkwardness nor the lack of support for (invariably non-POSIX) `\<char>` regex constructs; it does mention using an aux. variable as a workaround, however, although only with respect to making it easier to represent *whitespace*.
- All these parsing problems go away if the string that the regex engine should see is provided via a *variable* or via the output from a *command substitution*, as demonstrated above.

---

#### Optional reading: A portable *emulation* of word-boundary assertions with POSIX-compliant EREs (extended regular expressions):

- `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])` instead of `\<` / `[[:<:]]`
- `([^[:alnum:]_]|$)` instead of `\>` / `[[:>:]]`

Note: `\b` can't be emulated with a SINGLE expression - use the above in the appropriate places.

The potential caveat is that the above expressions will also *capture* the non-word character being matched, whereas true *assertions* such as `\<` / `[[:<:]]` and do not.

```
$foo = 'myword'
[[ $foo =~ (^|[^[:alnum:]_])myword([^[:alnum:]_]|$) ]] && echo YES
```

The above matches, as expected.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it applies across POSIX systems.

Comment: I've spent about an hour looking for this answer. Should be the solution! Thank you.

Comment: Incredibly through and well working answer. Should be the accepted answer. Thanks for this!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ChrisNagai; my pleasure. I appreciate the nice feedback.

Comment: `[[:\<:]]` does not work with Bash 5.2 on MacOS 13.2. `[[:<:]]` does work. With zsh `[[:\<:]]` is an invalid character class. `[[:<:]]` works.

Comment: @dawg, `[[ ' myword ' =~ [[:\<:]]myword[[:\>:]] ]] && echo YES` still works for me, both with a (Homebrew-installed) Bash v5.2.15(1), and with the system `zsh` (`/bin/zsh`, v5.8.1 as of macOS 13.1)

Comment: @mklement0: Try in a variable. With `[[ ' myword ' =~ $re ]] && echo MATCH || echo 'NO MATCH'` if you have `re='[[:<:]]myword'` it works but `re='[[:\<:]]myword'` does not. With the literal the opposite is true!

Comment: @dawg, yes, the use of ``\`` escaping is only required in _literal_, (of necessity) _unquoted_ use. So the variable-based equivalent of the command in my previous comment is: ``re='[[:<:]]myword[[:>:]]'; [[ ' myword ' =~ $re ]] && echo YES``. Note that this distinction isn't specific to the `=~` operator.

Comment: The careful, detailed, precise explanations make this answer a rare gem!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @TiStrga, and I appreciate the nice feedback.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly "\b", but for me more readable (and portable) than the other suggestions:

```
[[  $foo =~ (^| )myword($| ) ]]
```

Comment: This is brilliantly simple considering the alternatives

Comment: unfortunately only works for `foo=not-myword` but not for `foo=not-myword,myword`

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer focuses on using auxiliary variables to deal with the syntax oddities of regular expressions in Bash's `[[ ... ]]` expressions. Very good info.

However, the real answer is:

`\b` `\<` and `\>` do not work on OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) with bash version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0).

Instead, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

Comment: there's a comment on the original question from @mklement0 that says this too.

Comment: Given that the question has no platform-specific tagging, the answer is: If you're on _macOS_ / a _BSD_ platform, you're not affected by the bug in the OP, because `\ `-prefixed constructs are fundamentally unavailable there (and to use the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` alternatives there in an _unquoted_ `=~` RHS, you must escape them as `[[:\<:]]` and `[[:\>:]]`). On _Linux_, a Bash design flaw prevents the use of the available `\ `-prefixed constructs in (of necessity) unquoted `=~` RHS _literals_, and the accepted answer and others show effective workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Tangential to your question, but if you can use `grep -E` (or `egrep`, its effective, but obsolescent alias) in your script:

```
if grep -q -E "\b${myword}\b" <<<"$foo"; then
```

I ended up using this after flailing with bash's `=~`.

Note that while regex constructs `\<`, `\>`, and `\b` are not POSIX-compliant, both the BSD (macOS) and GNU (Linux) implementations of `grep -E` support them, which makes this approach widely usable in practice.

Small caveat (not an issue in the case at hand): By not using `=~`, you lose the ability to inspect capturing subexpressions (capture groups) via `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` later.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following to match word boundaries on older systems. The key is to wrap `$foo` with spaces since `[^[:alpha:]]` will not match words at the beginning or end of the list.

```
[[ " $foo " =~ [^[:alpha:]]myword[^[:alpha:]] ]]
```

Tweak the character class as needed based on the expected contents of `myword`, otherwise this may not be good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
bar='\<myword\>'
[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]
```

Comment: Yes, but that's effectively the same as the accepted answer. On Linux, both `bar='\<myword\>'` and `bar='\bmyword\b'` (or unquoted, as in the accepted answer, `bar=\\bmyword\\b`) work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep, which is more portable than bash's regexp like this:

```
if echo $foo | grep -q '\<myword\>'; then 
    echo "MATCH"; 
else 
    echo "NO MATCH"; 
fi
```

Comment: `grep` itself is portable, but `\<` as a grep feature is **not** -- unless you can point to where the POSIX specification defines it? I see no references in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html or http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/grep.html

Comment: (And `echo $foo` introduces its own bugs; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point about `\<`, `\>` and `\b` not being part of POSIX, but both the BSD (macOS) and GNU `grep` (Linux) implementations support them, which makes this approach widely usable in practice.

Comment: Aside from the fragility of `echo $foo` (unquoted variable reference) that Charles points out, note that `grep` by default uses only _basic_ regular expressions (BREs), whereas `=~` uses _extended_ regular expressions (EREs); to make the `grep` command work more like the latter, use `grep -E -q ...` - but then you'll have duplicated [this preexisting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962581/45375).