# Check if an element is present in a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, search

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to check if an element is present within an array  in Bash? I am looking for something similar to what I can do in Python, like:

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d']

if 'd' in arr:
    do your thing
else:
    do something
```

I've seen solutions using associative array for bash for Bash 4+, but I am wondering if there is another solution out there.

Please understand that I know the trivial solution is to iterate in the array, but I don't want that.

Comment: Don't confuse "concise" with "efficient". But no, there is no concise way in `bash` to do what you want with a simple array.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You could do:

```
if [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *" d "* ]]; then
    echo "arr contains d"
fi
```

This will give false positives for example if you look for "a b" -- that substring is in the joined string but not as an array element. This dilemma will occur for whatever delimiter you choose.

The safest way is to loop over the array until you find the element:

```
array_contains () {
    local seeking=$1; shift
    local in=1
    for element; do
        if [[ $element == "$seeking" ]]; then
            in=0
            break
        fi
    done
    return $in
}

arr=(a b c "d e" f g)
array_contains "a b" "${arr[@]}" && echo yes || echo no    # no
array_contains "d e" "${arr[@]}" && echo yes || echo no    # yes
```

Here's a "cleaner" version where you just pass the array name, not all its elements

```
array_contains2 () { 
    local array="$1[@]"
    local seeking=$2
    local in=1
    for element in "${!array}"; do
        if [[ $element == "$seeking" ]]; then
            in=0
            break
        fi
    done
    return $in
}

array_contains2 arr "a b"  && echo yes || echo no    # no
array_contains2 arr "d e"  && echo yes || echo no    # yes
```

---

For *associative arrays*, there's a very tidy way to test if the array contains a given *key*: The `-v` operator

```
$ declare -A arr=( [foo]=bar [baz]=qux )
$ [[ -v arr[foo] ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ -v arr[bar] ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

See [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) in the manual.

Comment: Does this code works both for numeric and string values ? For instance if my array contains both strings and array, can I search for both ?

Comment: yes. Bash will handle numeric values as strings without difficulty

Comment: to remove the first element of the positional parameters.

Comment: In my implementation I had to change "${!array}" to "${array[@]}" to work. I judged the "array_contains" and the "array_contains2" proposals safer because many who use grep return false positives.

Comment: Consider quoting `$seeking` so that it's not considered a pattern.

Comment: The `-v` operator only works in [Bash 4.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757358). In earlier versions, test for a key using `+_`:

`declare -A says`
`says[horse]=neigh`
`says[fish]=`
`[[ ${says[horse]+_} ]] && echo "horse: ${says[horse]}" || echo "horse doesn't exist"`
horse: neigh
`[[ ${says[fish]+_} ]] && echo "fish: ${says[fish]}" || echo "fish doesn't exist"`
fish: 
`[[ ${says[unicorn]+_} ]] && echo "unicorn: ${says[unicorn]}" || echo "unicorn doesn't exist"`
unicorn doesn't exist

Tested in v4.2.46. [Source](https://linuxhint.com/associative_arrays_bash_examples/)

Comment: @JosephCollins, I see your edit. I would encourage you to contribute a new answer. At me when you've done so and I'll vote for it.

Comment: I couldn't get either of the array_contains functions to work in Bash 4.3. But the solution using grep and here document worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Both of them work, I tested them back to bash 4.0. Did you see any errors?

Answer (score 38):

Obvious caveats aside, if your array was actually like the one above, you could do

```sh
if [[ ${arr[*]} =~ d ]]
then
  do your thing
else
  do something
fi
```

Comment: +1 for teaching something new. But `d` will match `xdy` as well.

Comment: @OlafDietsche That could be solved by writing it `if [[ ${arr[*]} =~ $(echo '\<d\>') ]]` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792702/does-bash-support-word-boundary-regular-expressions))

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. But how can I negate the outcome in case I don't have an else following? That would save some redundant code. [@Steven Penny](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny)

Comment: @SvenM. if [[ ! ${arr[*]} =~ d ]] ?

Answer (score 31):

1. Initialize array `arr` and add elements
2. set variable to search for `SEARCH_STRING`
3. check if your array contains element

```
    arr=()
    arr+=('a')
    arr+=('b')
    arr+=('c')
   
    SEARCH_STRING='b'

    if [[ " ${arr[*]} " == *"$SEARCH_STRING"* ]];
    then
        echo "YES, your arr contains $SEARCH_STRING"
    else
        echo "NO, your arr does not contain $SEARCH_STRING"
    fi
```

Comment: This was the only reply in the thread that worked for me, thank you!

Comment: This is fantastically concise and I was able to use this with `BASH_ARGV` to test whether a certain word was given as an argument that requires a different one-off setup was present without having to do some kind of `argparse` which is overkill for this case.

Comment: This is the only answer across StackOverflow that I found to be working.

Comment: A blog had almost this, but with spaces outside $SEARCH_STRING which did not work. I had to remove those spaces (and it also works if I remove the spaces inside the quotes on the left side).

Answer (score 22):

If array elements don't contain spaces, another (perhaps more readable) solution would be:

```
if echo ${arr[@]} | grep -q -w "d"; then 
    echo "is in array"
else 
    echo "is not in array"
fi
```

Comment: +1. Nice answer. This solution works for me to check whether a number is existed in a number array. While @Steven Penny's solution didn't work 100% correct in my case for number array.  if echo ${combined_p2_idx[@]} | grep -q -w $subset_id; then

Comment: I agree with @GoodWill. This should be the accepted answer. Other options weren't as robust.

Comment: It will error if you have negative numbers in the array

Comment: add `--` to signal the end of parameters and negative number will not treated as a param for grep

Comment: By far, the most elegant and understandable solution. Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 4):

As bash does not have a built-in *value* `in` *array* operator and the `=~` operator or the `[[ "${array[@]" == *"${item}"* ]]` notation keep confusing me, I usually combine `grep` with a here-string:

```
colors=('black' 'blue' 'light green')
if grep -q 'black' <<< "${colors[@]}"
then
    echo 'match'
fi
```

**Beware** however that this suffers from the same false positives issue as many of the other answers that occurs when the item to search for is fully contained, but is not equal to another item:

```
if grep -q 'green' <<< "${colors[@]}"
then
    echo 'should not match, but does'
fi
```

If that is an issue for your use case, you probably won't get around looping over the array:

```
for color in "${colors[@]}"
do
    if [ "${color}" = 'green' ]
    then
        echo "should not match and won't"
        break
    fi
done

for color in "${colors[@]}"
do
    if [ "${color}" = 'light green' ]
    then
        echo 'match'
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: @sec all that’s needed as @Querty’s answer above demonstrated to avoid false positives is to add `-x` to grep to match the entire line.

Answer (score 3):

```
array=("word" "two words") # let's look for "two words"
```

### using `grep` and `printf`:

```
(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -x -q "two words") && <run_your_if_found_command_here>
```

### using `for`:

```
(for e in "${array[@]}"; do [[ "$e" == "two words" ]] && exit 0; done; exit 1) && <run_your_if_found_command_here>
```

*For not_found results add `|| <run_your_if_notfound_command_here>`*

Comment: @Querty I don’t know why this isn’t the top answer. `grep -x...` makes it the simplest to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that might be faster, in terms of compute time, than iterating.  Not sure.  The idea is to convert the array to a string, truncate it, and get the size of the new array.

For example, to find the index of 'd':

```
arr=(a b c d)    
temp=`echo ${arr[@]}`
temp=( ${temp%%d*} )
index=${#temp[@]}
```

You could turn this into a function like:

```
get-index() {

    Item=$1
    Array="$2[@]"

    ArgArray=( ${!Array} )
    NewArray=( ${!Array%%${Item}*} )

    Index=${#NewArray[@]}

    [[ ${#ArgArray[@]} == ${#NewArray[@]} ]] && echo -1 || echo $Index

}
```

You could then call:

```
get-index d arr
```

and it would echo back 3, which would be assignable with:

```
index=`get-index d arr`
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's what I used:

```
expr "${arr[*]}" : ".*\<$item\>"
```

This works where there are no delimiters in any of the array items or in the search target. I didn't need to solve the general case for my applicaiton.