# How can I check if an associative array element exists in my Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have an array of animals:

```
declare -A animals=()
animals+=([horse])
```

and I want to check if an animal exists or not:

```
if [ -z "$animals[horse]"]; then
    echo "horse exists";
fi
```

but this does not work.

Comment: You might have good luck with this comprehensive set of answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219634/easiest-way-to-check-for-an-index-or-a-key-in-an-array/68701581#68701581

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241172/check-if-associative-array-element-exists-in-bash

Answer (score 28):

In `bash` 4.3, the `-v` operator can be applied to arrays.

```
declare -A animals
animals[horse]=neigh
# Fish are silent
animals[fish]=
[[ -v animals[horse] ]] && echo "horse exists"
[[ -v animals[fish] ]] && echo "fish exists"
[[ -v animals[unicorn] ]] || echo "unicorn does not exist"
```

In prior versions, you would need to be more careful distinguishing between the key not existing and the key referring to any empty string.

```
animal_exists () {
    # If the given key maps to a non-empty string (-n), the
    # key obviously exists. Otherwise, we need to check if
    # the special expansion produces an empty string or an
    # arbitrary non-empty string.
    [[ -n ${animals[$1]} || -z ${animals[$1]-foo} ]]
}

animal_exists horse && echo "horse exists"
animal_exists fish && echo "fish exists"
animal_exists unicorn || echo "unicorn does not exist"
```

Comment: Typo in first section of answer above. The last line should read: `[[ -v animals[unicorn] ]] || echo "unicorn does not exist"` and not `[[ -v animals[unicorn] ]] && echo "unicorn does not exist"`

Also, the test commands do not need to be double-brackets. Single brackets also work.

Comment: I prefer to use the double brackets, as `-v` is not part of the POSIX standard for `[`, and if you have `-v`, you have `[[` as well.

Comment: Note that `[[ -v foo[bar] ]]` works when your script has `set -u`.  Otherwise you get an error if you try to expand a nonexistent array member, so things like `test -n "${foo[bar]}"` will not work.

Answer (score 10):

There are several typos in your script

When I run it as it is, I get the following error messages from BASH:

```
1. animals: [horse]: must use subscript when assigning associative array
2. [: missing `]'
```

The first one says that if you want to use `horse` as an index to an associative array, you have to assign a value to it. An empty value (null) is ok.

```
-animals+=([horse])
+animals+=([horse]=)
```

The second message says that you need to separate the value you want to test and the bracket, as square bracket is considered a part of the value if not separated by spaces

```
-if [ -z "$animals[horse]"]; then
+if [ -z "$animals[horse]" ]; then
```

Finally, an element in an associative array exists when there is a value assigned to it (even if this value is null). As the question of testing if an array value is set has already been [answered on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221491/1328439), we can borrow the solution

```
-if [ -z "$animals[horse]"]; then
+if [ -n "${animals[horse]+1}" ]; then
```

---

For your convinience here is the complete script:

```
declare -A animals=()
animals+=([horse]=)

if [ -n "${animals[horse] + 1}" ]; then
    echo "horse exists";
fi
```

Comment: It's far simpler to write `animals[horse]=` than to use `+=`

Comment: @chepner fair enough, unless the OP wants to define several elements at once.

Answer (score 3):

In BASH you can do:

```
declare -A animals=()
animals+=([horse]=)

[[ "${animals[horse]+foobar}" ]] && echo "horse exists"
```

`"${animals[horse]+foobar}"` returns `foobar` if `horse` is a valid index in array otherwise it returns nothing.

Comment: Sorry, ... what's the meaning of `=` at the end of line "animals+=([horse]=)"

Comment: That is assignment of an empty value to index `horse`. `animals+=([horse])` will give syntax error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but came up when I was searching for an answer, my system doesnt have `bash 4.3` and I was specifically concerned about `animals[horse-2]` example

Another way you can do it is by dumping the contents out of the the array and then checking if the substring matches -

```
declare -A animals
animals[horse-2]=neigh-2
animals[dog]=woof
animals_as_string=$(declare -p animals)
other_animals="horse-2 moose cow"

for animal in $other_animals
do
  if [[ "$animal" == *$animals_as_string" ]]; then
    echo "found $animal"
  fi
done
```

Granted you'd need something a bit more to make sure you didn't find animals[horse-2] when searching for `animals[horse]` (if you had that in your array)