# Check if associative array element exists in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

In a bash script, I have a locale in a variable like so

```
locale=fr_ma
```

I also have an associative array like this

```
declare -A new_loc_map
new_loc[fr_ma]=en_ma
new_loc[el_gr]=en_gr
new_loc[sl_si]=en_si
```

I want to check if `new_loc` element with the key `${locale}` exists

I thought this should work but it doesn't:

```
if [[ -v "${new_loc[${locale}]}" ]]
    then
        echo -e "${locale} has a new_loc"
    fi
fi
```

any ideas on how otherwise I can test for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by checking if the variable is not an empty string instead.

Example:

```
locale=fr_ma
declare -A new_loc
new_loc[fr_ma]=en_ma
new_loc[el_gr]=en_gr

if [[ ! -z ${new_loc[$locale]} ]]; then
    echo "Locale ${locale} now maps to ${new_loc[$locale]}"
fi
```

Output:

```
Locale fr_ma now maps to en_ma
```

Comment: `-n` is the same as `! -z`

Answer (score 7):

For older verions of bash ([looks like](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS) `[[ -v array[index] ]]` was introduced in version 4.3), you can use the `${var-word}` form to test is a variable has been set:

```
$ zz="$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"
$ echo $zz
270502100415054
$ declare -a name
$ locale=foo

$ [[ ${name[$locale]-$zz} = "$zz" ]] && echo var is unset || echo var has a value
var is unset

$ name[$locale]=""
$ [[ ${name[$locale]-$zz} = "$zz" ]] && echo var is unset || echo var has a value
var has a value

$ [[ ${name[$locale]:-$zz} = "$zz" ]] && echo var is unset or empty || echo var has a value
var is unset or empty
```

The tricky part is devising a `$zz` string that won't appear as actual data in your array.

---

Much better suggestion from @chepner:

```
if [[ -z "${name[$locale]+unset}" ]]; then 
    echo "no name for $locale"
else 
    echo "name for $locale is ${name[$locale]}"
fi
```

Comment: Use `${name[$locale]+unset}`, which will produce a non-empty string if`$locale` is a key, or an empty string if not.

Comment: How do I put this condition inside an if statement?

Comment: `if [[ -z "${name[$locale]+unset}" ]]; then  echo "no name for $locale"; else echo "name for $locale is ${name[$locale]}"; fi`

Comment: Actually I think this is not correct in general (like in Perl `if ($h{x})` vs. `if (exists($h{x})`) if the element at an index may be the empty string.

Answer (score 4):

`-v` takes an (indexed) *name* as its argument, since you are trying to determine if the expansion makes sense in the first place.

```
if [[ -v new_loc[$locale] ]]; then
    echo "Locale ${locale} now maps to ${new_loc[$locale]}"
fi
```

### Word of warning

While the BASH manual page describes `-v` for `[[` *and* `test`, reliable results are returned from `[[` only.
Consider this (Bash 4.4):

```bash
> [ -v "$a[1]" ] && echo true
> a[1]=''
> [ -v "$a[1]" ] && echo true
> declare -p a
declare -a a=([1]="")
> [ -v $a[1] ] && echo true
> [[ -v $a[1] ]] && echo true
> [[ -v a[1] ]] && echo true
true
> [[ -v a[0] ]] && echo true
>
```

Comment: What is your `$BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: You need `bash` 4.3 or later for `-v` to work with an array index.