# exact match using if statement ? does partial match as well need to do exact match

Tags: bash, if-statement, pattern-matching, partial

I have the following command in my script. It works fine with one exception; it also matches partial entries. I want the match to be exact.

```
a=mary jane uger dodo baba
b=mary
c=ma    

if [[ "$a" =~ "$b" ]] && [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo it matches
else
    echo it does not match
fi
```

So no matter if in the if statement i use value $b or $c they both match. 
I want to ensure that the entry is fully match and not partially. So 
this should work and give exact match.

```
if [[ "$a" =~ "$b" ]]
```

and this should not work partial match

```
if [[ "$a" =~ "$c" ]]
```

Can someone help please?

here is my exact code

```
if [[ "$a" =~ "$b" ]]; then
      echo something     
fi
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=~`.

Comment: @devnull: I believe you misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Your assignment to `a` is invalid. It will try to run the command `jane` with the variable `a` set to `mary` in its environment.

Comment: yes the == will not work in this case at all.

Comment: consider adding the output of `bash --version ; uname` to your question. Good luck.

Comment: Why does == not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z='\>'
[[ $a =~ $b$z ]] # true
[[ $a =~ $c$z ]] # false
```

[does bash support word boundary regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9792702/#23096528)

Comment: cool this works thanks Steven .. I had to remove the quotes around my variable. Can you tell me what does including the '\>' does if u get a chance?

Answer (score 2):

Put a space or end anchor in in the end for regex comparison to make sure there is **no partial word match**:

```
a='mary jane uger dodo baba'
b='mary'
c='ma'

# will match
[[ "$a" =~ "$b"( |$) ]]

# won't match
[[ "$a" =~ "$c"( |$) ]]
```

Comment: hi .. it does not make any difference .,,. it still matches the partially .. I tried it and it made no difference

Comment: That means you made some mistake in copying this script. See this working demo: http://ideone.com/JGZ2P9

Comment: echo $a

    if [[ "$a" =~ "$1"( |$ ) ]] && [ -n "$1" ]; then
        echo it matches
    else
    echo it does not match
    fi

Comment: Don't place code in comment. I provided you a working demo. You can also provide your code in same demo and show how it is not working.

Comment: I typed this exactly as you have it. Now my if statement is not working at all.              [[ "$a" =~ "$c"( |$) ]]

Comment: That should work if used properly. Asi said provide a link to ideone demo to show it is not working.