# Bash check shows file exists for non-existent files?

Tags: bash

Run the following in bash:

```
   stuff=`rpm -ql <some package> | grep dasdasdfd`
```

(non existent file in package, exit code = 1, stdout is empty)

```
  if [ -f $stuff ]; then echo "whaaat"; fi
```

Above command checks if file exists... but:

```
file $stuff
```

Just prints usage info for file... and

```
stat $stuff
```

Missing operand...

Can someone please explain why? Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? I just want to make sure that a file that's in the package is present on fs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to surround `$stuff` in quotes

```
if [ -f "$stuff" ]; then
```

As a general rule, you almost *always* want to add quotes around pathnames everywhere you use them.

I find it more useful to think or variables in shell scripting as "macros", which are expanded on first use to their value. This is different from variables in almost every other programming language.

So if `$stuff` contains `hello world` (notice the space), it would be the same as if you've typed:

```
[ -f hello world ]
```

which is obviously an error.

In this case, you mentioned that you're dealing with a non-existent file, so `$stuff` is actually empty, which would be like typing:

```
[ -f ]
```

Which is actually valid, but always succeeds. This is a bit of obscure `test` behaviour, from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) we read that `test` always succeeds if there if only a single argument (in this case, the argument is `-f`):

> 1 argument:
>   Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

This is probably to facilitate the writing of:

```
[ $variable_that_may_or_may_not_be_defined ]
```

If you add quotes, you're passing 2 arguments, and more sane things happen:

```
if [ -f "" ]; then
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that... I must be dumb dumb dumb... Thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain why `[ -f` or `test -f` returns 0 without argument? The documentation does not really mention that case.

Comment: `[ string ]` is interpreted as `[ -n string ]`. `[ -f ]` is equivalent to `[ -n -f ]` which is always true: `-f` is not an empty string.

Answer (score 6):

[Martin Tournoij's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303736/45375) and [DevSolar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303852/45375) both provide correct solutions and helpful background info: with respect to `[ ... ]` in one case, and `[[ ... ]]` in the other.

Since it may not be obvious **if and when to choose `[[ ... ]]` over `[ ... ]`** (and its (virtual) alias, `test ...`), let me attempt a summary:

- If your **code must be *portable* (POSIX-compliant)**, you **MUST use `[ ... ]` (or `test ...`)**.

  - Tokens inside `[ ... ]` are **parsed just like arguments passed to an executable**, so you **must double-quote your variable references**, unless you explicitly want all shell expansions - notably word splitting  (automatic splitting into multiple tokens by whitespace) and globbing - applied to them.
  - `[ -f "$stuff" ] # double-quoting required, if $stuff has embedded whitespace`
- If you know that your **code will be run *with `bash`*, you can use `[[ ... ]]`** for **more features and fewer surprises**.

  - Tokens inside `[[ ... ]]` are parsed in a **special context** in which **neither word splitting nor pathname expansion (globbing) are applied** (though other expansions, such as parameter expansion, *do* occur), so there is **typically no need to double-quote variable references**.
  - `[[ -f $stuff ]] # double-quoting optional`

<sup>Note that `ksh` and `zsh` also support `[[ ... ]]` (presumably with subtle variations in behavior).</sup>

For more background info, such as the additional features that `[[ ... ]]` offers, read on.

---

**`[[ ... ]]` improves on `[ ... ]` / `test ...` as follows**:

<sup>"RHS" below means "right-hand side", i.e., the right operand of a binary operator.</sup>

- **(typically) requires NO quoting of variable references** (except on the RHS of `==` and `=~` to specify a *literal* string or substring(s))

  - `f='some file'; [[ -f $f ]]  # ok, double quotes optional`
  - `v='*'; [[ $v == '*' ]]      # ok, double quotes optional`
  - Neither word splitting nor pathname expansion is applied inside `[[ ... ]]`, so it's safe to use unquoted references to variables whose values have embedded whitespace and/or values such as `*` that would normally lead to globbing.
- offers **string *pattern* matching** with `=` / `==`, with an *unquoted* pattern on the RHS (or at least unquoted pattern metachars.)

  - `[[ abc == a* ]] && echo yes  # matches; use of = instead of == works too`
  - *Caveat*: Thus, on the RHS of `=` / `==` you *must* double-quote variable references (or single-quote literals) if you want their values to be treated as *literals*.

    - `v='a*'; [[ abc == "$v" ]] # does NOT match`
- offers **regex matching with `=~`**, with an *unquoted* extended regular expression on the RHS (or at least unquoted regex metachars.)

  - `[[ abc =~ ^a.+$ ]] && echo yes  # matches`
  - *Caveat*: Thus, on the RHS of `=~` you *must* double-quote variable references (or single-quote literals) if you want their values to be treated as *literals*.

    - `v='a.+'; [[ abc =~ ^"$v"$ ]] # does NOT match`
    - Also note that the unquoted / quoted distinction was only introduced in bash 3.2 - you can still use `shopt -s compat31` to have single- and double-quoted strings treated as regexes, too.
  - *Caveat*: The regex dialect understood by `=~` is *platform-specific*, so a regex that works on one platform may not work on another (this is one of the few cases where bash's behavior is platform-dependent). For instance, on Linux you can use `\b` and `\<` / `\>` for word-boundary assertions, whereas BSD/macOS only supports `[[:<]]` and `[[:>]]`, which, in turn, Linux doesn't support - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696899/45375) of mine.
- offers grouping and negation with ***unescaped* `(`, `)`, and `!` chars**.
- offers **use of `&&` and `||`** (Boolean AND and OR)

  - `[[ (3 -gt 2) && ! -f / ]] && echo yes`
  - Note that, inside `[[ ... ]]`, `&&` has *higher* precedence than `||` - unlike OUTSIDE (as so-called [command-]list operators, where they combine entire commands / command lists), where they have *equal* precedence.
  - (while `[` and `test` have  `-a` and `-o`, [even the POSIX spec. for `test` cautions against their use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html))
- within `[[ ... ]]`, you **may spread your conditional across *multiple lines* for readability** without the need for the line-continuation char. (`\`), assuming the line breaks come **after `&&` or `||`**, as [codeforester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6862601/codeforester) points out.
- **`[[ ... ]]` is *faster*** than `[ ... ]`, though that will typically not matter.

  - If you are interested in relative performance, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194257/45375) of mine.

---

**Implementation notes re `[` and `test`**:

- `[[` a is shell *keyword* (supported in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`), which allows for different parsing rules, as described above.
- By contrast, `[` and `test` are *builtins* in all major POSIX-like shells (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `dash`).
- In addition, both `[` and `test` exist as external *utilities* (executable *files* that require a *separate process* to invoke), as [mandated by POSIX](http://man.cx/test).

  - In fact, you *need* external utility versions so as to be able to use `[` or `test` in "shell-less" invocation scenarios such as when passing a test to `find -exec` or `xargs`.
  - While the `[` utility could conceivably be implemented as a symlink to the  `test` utility (as long as `test` knows how it was invoked and enforces the closing `]` when invoked as `[`), in practice they are often (always?) separate executables (true on Linux and macOS / BSD, for instance; on Linux, their content differs, whereas on macOS / BSD their content is identical (they are copies of the same file)).

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to put `$stuff` in quotes, as Carpetsmoker said.

But since this is tagged bash, and because catering for whitespace in filenames is a pain, you could go for:

```
if [[ -f $stuff ]]
```

As opposed to `[` which is an alias for `test`, the `[[` construct "knows" how to handle the contents of `$stuff` correctly.

Comment: Good to know, I use [[ for logical equivalence tests with != and ==

Comment: @Nik: That's one of the additional features of `[[`: The `=~` operator for matching strings against a RegEx.