# How to use function return value in while test in the bash script

Tags: bash

Here is my code abstract. I use the result of the comparison between the `return_val` in `func` and `"true"` to decide the while termination condition. But the echoes don't work at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
    a=$1
    b=$2
    echo $a
    echo $b
    if ((a > b)) 
    then 
        return_val="true"
    else
        return_val="false"
    fi  
}

c=1
d=4
while [[ $(func $c $d) && ("$return_val"!="true") ]]
do
    ((c++))
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to see the output from your `echo` command, you need to separate the *stdout output* from the *return (exit) code*:

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
    local a=$1 b=$2
    echo "$a"  # stdout output
    echo "$b"
    if (( a > b ))  # see below for how this could be simplified.
    then 
        return 0 # set exit code
    else
        return 1
    fi  
}

c=1 d=4
while ! func $c $d
do
    ((c++))
done
```

That way, you're free to use the function *directly* (prefixed with `!` to negate the test's outcome), without a command substitution, and let its *return (exit) code* drive the outcome of the `while` loop condition (an exit code of `0` meaning success, any other meaning failure).

By using just `! func $c $d` as the condition, `func`'s stdout output is simply printed as is.

---

*Addendum*: [Billy Wayne McCann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426362/45375) points out that there's no strict need to use explicit `return` statements to set the exit code (but there's no need to use `test`<sup>[1]</sup>).

`(( a > b ))` can be used *by itself* as the last statement in the function, to set the exit code *implicitly*:

If there's no explicit `return` statement, it is a function's *last* command that sets its exit code (the same applies analogously to *scripts* in the absence of an `exit` statement).

`(( ... ))` sets the exit code to `1`, if `...` evaluates to `0`, and `1` otherwise (any non-negative result). A Boolean expression such as `a > b` results in `1`, if the expression is true, and `0` otherwise. Therefore, `(( a > b ))` by itself does the same thing implicitly that the above `if` statement does *explicitly*:

```
func(){
    local a=$1 b=$2
    echo "$a"  # stdout output
    echo "$b"
    (( a > b ))  # exit code implicitly set to 0, if test *succeeds*, 1 otherwise
}
```

<sup>[1] Using `test` or `[ ... ]` is the POSIX-compliant way to evaluate a condition. Unless your code must be POSIX-compliant, Bash's `[[ ... ]]` and `(( ... ))` (for *arithmetic* Boolean tests) are the better choice - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375</sup>

Comment: Sorry, echoes are used to debug. I have learnt  that we should return the exit status instead of value.

Comment: @CodingTheLife: That's what exactly what this solution does: the function's _exit code_ determines when to exit the loop. _Independently_ of that, whatever output the command that forms the condition produces is passed through. If you do _not_ want that output, use `>/dev/null` to suppress stdout, `2>/dev/null` to suppress stderr, and `&>/dev/null` to suppress both. Since your question states that "echoes don't work" - what did you mean by that, given that this solution does "make them work"?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather have function return a value.

```
#!/bin/bash

func(){
    a=$1
    b=$2
    echo $a
    echo $b
    if ((a > b)) 
    then 
        return 0 # 0 means success
    else
        return 1 # non-zer0 means failure
    fi  
}

c=1
d=4
until (func $c $d) #While ! success, do something..
do
    ((c++))
done
```

Note: The parenthesis around `func $c $d` are only for readability. Not required really.

Comment: @anishane: Using redundant parentheses there has the effect of creating a redundant subshell, because that's what parentheses do in bash. Anyway, IMHO, `while func $c $d; do` is perfectly readable (at least, once you get used to bash).

Answer (score 1):

Forcing a return of 0 or 1 isn't the proper way to do this.  You want to return the true exit status of the test, not a forced return status. There's really no need for the `if ... then` block.

Functions automatically return their exit status. This exit status of the function is the status of the final statement. Hence, one can place `test` as the final statement in `func`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

func(){
    local a=$1 
    local b=$2
    test $a -lt $b  #use exit status directly
}

c=1 
d=4

while func $c $d  #while c is less than d
do
   ((c++)) 
done
```

Comment: "isn't the proper way to do this." is hyperbole - the accepted answer is _proper_, but _needlessly verbose_.  `((a > b)) ` by itself would do as the last statement -  no need to use the  less flexible and less powerful  `test` builtin instead.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: your suggestion to _simplify_ the code by simply letting the outcome of a test determine a function's exit code _implicitly_ is  a good one. While the `if` statement in the accepted answer is effectively _redundant_, it doesn't, however, _mask_ the `(( … ))` expression's exit code, because `(( … ))` itself only ever sets exit code 0 or 1. (Even if there _were_ masking, it would only matter if you subsequently tested for a _specific_ exit code set, which rarely happens; in the case at hand, `while` only cares about 0 vs. non-zero.)

Comment: `a` and `b` are also needlessly verbose; `func () { test "$1" -lt "$2"; }` would work identically since you aren't modifying the arguments.