# bash script with grep command understanding

Tags: bash, grep

I posted earlier with something similar to this. I am trying to check if a user is online with the command `$ ./user mburkhar` which prints out `mburkhar is logged on`. My program works correctly but if I just type `$ ./user mb` is also states `mb is logged on`. What I have is fine, but is there a way to match what the user typed in exactly instead of slightly matching the first 2 characters..?

Here is my program so you can see what I did:

```
# Check if a user is logged on

if [ -z $1 ] ; then
    read user
else
    user=$1
fi

if [ `who | cut -d" " -f1 | grep $1` ] ; then
    echo "$1 is logged on"
else
    echo "$1 is either not valid or logged on"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grep's `-w` (`--word-regexp`) option to match only entire words. Replacing `grep $1` with `grep -w $1` in your script should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482236/45375):

`-w` works well and is widely supported (GNU Grep, BSD Grep), but [it is not POSIX-compliant](http://man.cx/grep).

In your case, given that your output lines contain *just* a username each and nothing else, using `-x` - to match *entire* lines - would make sense too (and it *is* POSIX-compliant).
Also, since you're searching for a *literal* username, it's good practice to use `grep`'s `-F` option to indicate just that.

Using `[ $(...) ]` (or `` [ `...` ] ``) to test for nonempty output from a command is somewhat fragile and inefficient; it's better and simpler to:

- use commands directly
- base the test on the *exit* code
- and suppress stdout output, if needed

  - `grep`'s `-q` option not only suppresses stdout, but also makes the search potentially more efficient by terminating once the *first* match is found (with exit code `0` to indicate success):

    ```
    if who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep -Fxq "$1"; then # ...
    ```

Similarly, `[ -z $1 ]` is fragile in that would break if an argument with embedded whitespace is passed - not likely in *this* case, but it's [better to get in the habit of using `[[ -z $1 ]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375) (or, if you must remain POSIX-compliant, `[ -z "$1" ]`).
Outside of `[[ ... ]]`, it makes sense to habitually double-quote variable references, such as the `$1` in the `grep` command.

If we put it all together:

```
# Check if a user is logged on
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    read user
else
    user=$1
fi

if who | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep -Fxq "$1"; then
    echo "$1 is logged on"
else
    echo "$1 is either not valid or logged on"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the start and end of string anchors like this:

```
if [ -z $1 ] ; then
    read user
else
    user="^$1$"
fi

if [ $(who | cut -d" " -f1 | grep $user | uniq ) ] ; then
    echo "$1 is logged on"
else
    echo "$1 is either not valid or logged on"
fi
```

I also added the `uniq` to remove duplicate matches, in case an user got more than one tty, or `[` will exit with: `[: too many arguments`