# Is there a difference between negating before/after a test command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I've been Bash scripting for a while and I'm wondering if there's any difference between these two forms of negation with the `test` command:

```
if [ ! condition ]; then
fi

if ! [ condition ]; then
fi
```

The first tells the shell to pass the arguments `! condition` to test, letting the program take care of the negation itself. On the other hand, the second passes `condition` to test and lets the shell itself negate the error code.

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of when choosing between these two forms? What values of `$condition` could make the results differ between them?

(I seem to remember reading an article a while ago discussing this, but I don't remember how to find it/exactly what was discussed.)

Comment: Not really a pitfall, since it's hard to construct a realistic scenario where this would happen, but keep in mind that in `! [ condition ]` the `!` is a shell operator, negating the exit status of a command, while in `[ ! condition ]` the `!` is just a string argument to the `[` command. After `foo="! bar"`, compare `[ "$foo" ]` with `[ $foo ]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To build on [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s insightful comment on the question:

- In `[ ! condition ]`, the `!` is just **an *argument* to the `[` builtin** (an effective alias of the `test` builtin); it so happens that `[` / `test` interprets argument `!` as negation.
- In `! [ condition ]`, the `!` is **a *shell keyword* that negates whatever command it is followed by** (which happens to be `[` in this case).

One thing that the `! [ condition ]` syntax implicitly gives you is that negation applies to whatever `[ condition ]` evaluates to *as a whole*, so if that is the intent, you needn't worry about operator precedence.

**Performance-wise**, which syntax you choose probably doesn't make much of a difference; quick tests suggest:

- If `condition` is literally the same in both cases, passing the `!` as an *argument to `[`* is negligibly faster.
- If `!` is used as a *keyword*, and you are therefore able to simplify the condition by not worrying about precedence, it may be slightly faster (e.g, `! [ 0 -o 1 ]` vs. `[ ! \( 0 -o 1 \) ]`; note that the POSIX spec. discourages use of `-a` and `-o` due to ambiguity).

That said, if we're talking about ***Bash***, then you should **consider using `[[` instead of `[`**, because `[[` is a *shell keyword* that parses the enclosed expression in a special context that:

- offers more features
- allows you to safely combine expressions with `&&` and `||`
- comes with fewer surprises
- is also slightly faster (though that will rarely matter in pratice)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375) of mine.

Answer (score 2):

`!` negates the exit code of following command :

```
$ ! test 1 = 1 || echo $?  # negate command with true expression
1
```

As said in man  page, `test` (and similar `[` builtin) exit with the status determined by following expression :

```
$ test ! 1 = 1 || echo $?  # return false expression
1
$ [ ! 1 = 1 ] || echo $?
1
```

For a given expression :

- on one side you negate the `test` command that exit with true expression status.
- on the other side, you negate an expression and the `test` command (or `[`) exit with its false status

Both will have the same effect.

So I would say that these syntax are equivalent. With the advantage for external `!` to allow negate compound tests :

```
$ ! [ 1 = 1 -a 2 = 2 ] || echo $?
1
```

Comment: You might care to note that a minor adaptation of the third example in the first set also reports `1`: `test ! false || echo $?`.  That's because the test is checking whether the string (`true` or `false`) is empty or not.  Similarly with the second example in the first set; replacing `true` by `false` does not change the result.

Comment: You're right. Replaced it with what i should be : an expression.

Comment: Maybe you should note that `==` works on `bash` but not `dash`.

Comment: Updated with POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference if `test`/`[` faces an error. Consider:

```
x=abc
if   [ ! "$x" -gt 0 ]; then echo "first true"; fi
if ! [   "$x" -gt 0 ]; then echo "second true"; fi
```

The output is:

```
bash: [: abc: integer expression expected
second true
```

Unlike `[[ .. ]]`, `test`/`[` works like regular utility and signals errors by returning `2`. That's a falsy value, and with `!` outside the brackets, the shell inverts it just the same as a regular negative result from the test would be inverted.

With `[[ .. ]]` the behaviour is different, in that a syntax error in the condition is a syntax error for the shell, and the shell itself exits with an error:

```
if [[ a b ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

prints only

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `b'
```

with no output from the `echo`s.

On the other hand, arithmetic tests work differently within `[[ .. ]]` so  `[[ "$x" -gt 0 ]]` would never give an error.