# How to combine AND and OR condition in bash script for if condition?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

I was trying to combine logical AND & OR in a bash script within if condition. Somehow I am not getting the desired output and it is hard to troubleshoot.
I am trying to validate the input parameters passed to a shell script for no parameter and the first parameter passed is valid or not.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] && ([ "$1" == "ABC" ] || [ "$1" == "DEF" ] || [ "$1" == "GHI" ] || [ "$1" == "JKL" ]) 
then
echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh [ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL]"
exit 1
fi
```

Can anyone point out what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The immediate problem with your statement is one of *logic*: you probably meant to write:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || ! ([ "$1" = "ABC" ] || [ "$1" = "DEF" ] || [ "$1" = "GHI" ] || [ "$1" = "JKL" ]) 
then
  echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh [ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL]" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

That is: abort, if either more than 1 argument is given OR if the single argument given does NOT equal one of the acceptable values.

Note the `!` to negate the expression in parentheses and the use of the POSIX-compliant form of the string equality operator, `=` (rather than `==`).

However, given that you're using Bash, you can make do with a single `[[ ... ]]` conditional and Bash's regular-expression matching operator, `=~`:

```
if [[ $# -ne 1 || ! $1 =~ ^(ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL)$ ]] 
then
  echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh [ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL]" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

If POSIX compliance is not required, `[[ ... ]]` is preferable to `[ ... ]` for [a variety of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375).
In the case at hand, `$#` and `$1` didn't need quoting, and `||` could be used *inside* the conditional.

Note that `=~` as used above works in Bash 3.2+, whereas the implicit `extglob` syntax used in [anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067462/45375) requires Bash 4.1+;
in earlier versions you can, however, explicitly enable (and restore to its original value after) the `extglob` shell option: `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 9):

BASH actually allows use of extended glob inside `[[ ... ]]` and have `&&` inside as well.

So you can do:

```
if [[ $# -ne 1 && $1 == @(ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL) ]]; then
   echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh [ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL]"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Yes that will also work but this one is shorter since it has only one `[[ ... ]]` expression

Comment: However I think in this code it should be `$1 != ...` but I just replicated OP's conditions

Comment: ++, but please note that the implicit `extglob` syntax only works in Bash 4.1+.

Comment: Prior to 4.1, you just need to explicitly enable it with `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `[...]` in bash is equivalent to the same `test` command (check the man page), so those && and || are not logical operators, but rather the shell equivalents
- Parentheses in POSIX shell are not a grouping operator.  They will work here, but they open a subshell, you are better off using standard test options of `-a` and `-o` (making your if statement `if [ "$#" -ne 1 -a \( "$1" == "ABC" -o "$1" == "DEF" -o "$1" == "GHI" -o "$1" == "JKL" \) ]`, though based on your logic, it sounds like you actually want something like `if [ "$#" -ne 1 -o \( "$1" != "ABC" -a "$1" != "DEF" -a "$1" != "GHI" -a "$1" != "JKL" \) ]`.  You probably can get better results with a `case` statement like follows:

---

```
usage() {
    echo "Usage: ./myscript.sh [ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL]"
}


if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] 
then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    ABC)
        echo "Found ABC"
        ;;
    DEF)
        echo "Found DEF"
        ;;
    GHI)
        echo "Found GHI"
        ;;
    JKL)
        echo "Found JKL"
        ;;
    *)
        usage
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

If you want to pass a set of possible static arguments in, you might want to look at the `getopts` special shell command.

Comment: Good points; quibble: the [POSIX spec. for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) itself warns against use of `-a`, `-o`, and `()`: "The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. (Many expressions using them are ambiguously defined by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.) "

Comment: That's a good quibble.  How would you alternately do this with just POSIX?  command groups (`{...}`), &&, and ||?

Comment: @Taywee: correct, you would use `[ ... ] && { [ ... ] || [ ... ]; }`

Comment: You can also shorten the `case` statement with `ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL) echo "Found $1" ;;`.

Comment: Command  groups are a good idea (to avoid a subshell); a pitfall worth pointing out: with `test`, `-a` has higher precedence than `-o`, but the shell's `&&` and `||` have _equal_ precedence.

Comment: @chepner I know, I'm operating under the assumption that they'll probably do different things and might want to be handled independently.