# bash cd up to specific directory

Tags: bash

I'm working on an install script (written in bash) for a library.  The install script lives in a subdirectory of the project's base directory.  I'd like users to be able to run the install script from anywhere under the base directory, so I'm trying to make the script `cd` to the base directory before executing other commands.

I'm looking at something like

```
while [[ $PWD == *"ProjectName"* ] && [ $PWD -ne *"ProjectName" ]]; do cd .. ;done
```

I'm open to cleaner solutions, but at the very least I'd like to understand why the above does not work.  No doubt I have brackets in the wrong spots, but I'm not sure where to put them.

Comment: Do you know where the install script lives in relation to the base directory? First cd to the script containing the script, then go up the appropriate number of levels.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38067413/3266847) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16203088/3266847) shows you how to combine multiple conditions, but your approach might not be optimal to begin with.

Comment: You either use `[[...]]` or `[...]` - NOT combinations of both. It would be either `[[ $PWD = *ProjectName ]]` or `[ "$PWD" = *ProjectName ]` (double-quoting of all vars require in `[...]` (equivalent to `test`), but not `[[...]]`). You do not use `-ne` for comparing strings (it is a numerical not equal to), use `!=` for string inequality. Also string equality is properly `=`, but most will support `==` as well. A condition of `[[ $PWD = .. ]] && [[ $PWD != .. ]]` will never test `true`

Answer (score 0):

The following does what I want. Thanks to everyone (especially @David C. Rankin) for their helpful comments.

```
while [[ "$PWD" = *"ProjectName"* && ! "$PWD" = *"ProjectName" ]]
      do
      cd ..
done
```