# What is the difference between IF [ condition ] & [[ condition ]] , -eq and == in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

Is there a difference between the two code snippets below

```
    if [[ $a == "1" ]];then
       echo $a
```

and

```
    if [ $a == "1" ];then
       echo $a
```

Also, is there a difference when I use `-eq` in place of `==` in the above snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, numeric comparison is handled differently than string comparison

For numbers,

```
$var1 -eq $var2   // =
$var1 -gt $var2   // >
$var1 -ge $var2   // >=
$var1 -lt $var2   // <
$var1 -le $var2   // <=
$var1 -ne $var2   // !=
```

For strings

```
$str1 = $str2   // they are equal
str1 != str2    // not equal
str             // Returns True if str is not null.
-n str          // Returns True if the length of str is greater than zero.
-z str          // Returns True if the length of str is equal to zero.
```

Note that == is the same as =

Also note that the == operates differently in a double bracket comparison (this is where your [ condition ] vs [[ condition ]] question comes in) when doing pattern matching.  These comparisons/operators all all explained at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: ++ for a helpful overview, though I suggest adding string operators `<` and `>` for symmetry (even though they're used much less frequently).
For convenience, here is a direct link to the explanation of the difference between `[ … ]` and `[[ … ]]` from the page you link to: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Answer (score 4):

- As for your main question: it is a duplicate of: [Is [[ ]] preferable over [ ] in bash scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash-scripts)

  - You can also find a (hopefully) comprehensive discussion of the differences between `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375) of mine.
    In short: `[[ ... ]]` is parsed more like you'd expect in a regular programming language, and it implements many useful extensions, but it is not POSIX-compliant.
- As for "is there a difference when I use `-eq` in place of `==`?":

  - `=` and `==`, its Bash alternative, perform *string* comparison.

    - Additionally, inside `[[ ... ]]` *only*, if the RHS of `=` or `==` is *unquoted*, it is interpreted as a glob-style *pattern* to match the LHS against; contrast `[[ 'a' == '*' ]] && echo match` with `[[ 'a' == * ]] && echo match`
    - Note that if you use `[ ... ]` (rather than `[[ ... ]]`) for POSIX compliance (portable use with `/bin/sh`), you should only use `=`, not `==`; while Bash accepts `==` inside `[ ... ]` too, other shells don't.
  - `-eq` performs *integer* comparison
  - Other string/numeric operator pairs exist (e.g., `-lt` for numeric less-than vs. `<` for *alphabetical* (string) less-than, based on textual sort order).
- [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) lists all operators you can use inside `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` (and also with `test`, which is effectively an alias of `[ ... ]`).

  - Additionally, inside `[[ ... ]]`, regular expression-matching operator `=~` is available - see [Bash Conditional Constructs](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)