# exclamation mark to test variable is true or not in bash shell

Tags: shell

I know in shell the exclamation mark can invert the outcome of condition. Here I wanna use it to test variable is true or false .

```
#! /bin/bash
bat=false
if [ ! $bar ]; then
    echo 'bar is false'
else
   echo 'bar is true'
fi
```

I was expecting 'bar is false'. However it turned out the other way. Then I use  "$bar" == "false". It is right.

So what is the tips for using exclamation mark. Would it only invert outcome when we test about file ?

Comment: Shells don't have boolean values, just string variables. `true` and `false` are both just strings, not inherently different from any other word like `kitten`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**`[ ! $bar ]` treats `$bar` as a *string*, and *any nonempty* string is considered "true"** - including literal `false`; in other words: `[ ! 'true' ]` && `[ ! 'false' ]` *both* evaluate to "false", because the operands are nonempty strings in both cases and `!` negates the outcome.

Therefore, you must use *string* comparison:

```
bar=false
if [ ! "$bar" = 'true' ]; then  # same as: [ "$bar" != 'true' ]
    echo 'bar is false'
else
    echo 'bar is true'
fi
```

In Bash, you can also use `[[ ! $bar == 'true' ]]` or `[[ $bar != 'true' ]]`; unless you need to remain POSIX-compliant, [I suggest using `[[ ... ]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320710/45375).

---

In the context of `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` (Bash-specific), **variable values are *strings* by default**, and, generally, **POSIX-like shells  *have no explicit Boolean data type***.

Unary operator `!` interprets its operand *implicitly* as a Boolean, and a ***string* in a Boolean context** is interpreted as follows:

- only an ***empty* string** is considered **"false"** (exit code `1`(!))
- ***any nonempty* string** - including *literal* `false` - is considered **"true"** (exit code `0`(!))

Thus, `! $bar` evaluates to "false", because `$bar` - containing nonempty string `'false'` - evaluates to "true", and `!` inverts that.

---

`!` can also be used outside of conditionals to directly negate the success status of commands (including `[`).
Since `false` and `true` also exist as *command names* (typically, as shell builtins), you *could* do the following, but do note that it only works as intended with variable values that are either the literals `false` or `true`:

```
bar=false
if ! "$bar"; then
   echo 'bar is false'
else
   echo 'bar is true'
fi
```

---

#### Background information

POSIX-like shells only have 2 basic (scalar) data types:

- strings (by default):

  - In `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` conditionals, operators  `=` (`==` in Bash), `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` perform *string* comparison.
- integers:

  - In `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]` conditionals, distinct *arithmetic* operators (`-eq`, `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge`) must be used to perform *numerical* comparison
  - Alternatively, in an arithmetic expansion (`$(( ... ))`), `==`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` have their usual, *numeric* meaning.
    In Bash, you can also use `(( ... ))` as an arithmetic *conditional*.

Note: Per POSIX, you cannot *type* a variable as an integer (because there is no way to *declare* a shell variable), so it is only implicitly *treated as one* in comparisons using arithmetic operators / in arithmetic contexts.
In Bash, however, you can *declare* integer variables with `declare -i` / `local -i`, but in conditionals / arithmetic contexts it is still the choice of operator / arithmetic context that determines whether the value is treated as a string or as an integer.

---

Booleans in shells are expressed *implicitly* as *exit codes*, in a *reversal* of the usual Boolean-to-integer mapping:

- "true" maps to exit code `0`(!)
- "false" is expressed as exit code `1`(!) or any other *nonzero* exit code.

Comment: thanks so much. Now my confusion is solved. Another quick question,  is double quote around $bar is required or not . I just tried if [ $bar ], which is also working as expected.

Comment: @nathan: The short of it: to be safe, double-quote. There are cases when you don't strictly have to, such as here, but the rules aren't easy to remember. It is safe to double-quote whenever you want a variable value to be used as-is. To learn more, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/54804).

Answer (score 3):

See the POSIX specification of [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for details of the portable use of the `[` or `test` utility.

If you use `[ ! $bar ]` you are playing with fire.

- If `$bar` is an empty string, it degenerates to the one-argument form of test, with that argument being `!`, and exits successfully because `!` is not an empty string.
- If `$bar` is not an empty string, then the arguments are `!` and the value of `$bar`, which establishes that the non-empty string is non-empty, and then inverts the condition, so it exits with a failure status.

You should normally write `[ ! "$bar" ]` which will then work correctly if `$bar` is empty.  You could (arguably should) use the explicit tests:

- `[ -z "$bar" ]` to test for an empty (zero-length) string, and
- `[ -n "$bar" ]` to test for a non-empty string

but the quotes are mandatory to avoid confusion.  The `n`on-empty and `z`ero-length are mnemonic terms.

```
$ bar=
$ [ ! $bar ] || echo Test failed
$ bar=xyz
$ [ ! $bar ] || echo Test failed
Test failed
$ [ ! "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
Test failed
$ bar=
$ [ ! "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
$ [ -n "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
Test failed
$ [ -z "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
$
```

Some people prefer the Bash (Korn shell, …) operator `[[` which behaves differently.  You could experiment with variations on the theme of this code:

```
set -x
bar=
[ ! $bar ] || echo Test failed
bar=xyz
[ ! $bar ] || echo Test failed
[ ! "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
bar=
[ ! "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
[ -n "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
[ -z "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
bar=xyz
[ -n "$bar" ] || echo Test failed
[ -z "$bar" ] || echo Test failed

bar=
[[ ! $bar ]] || echo Test failed
bar=xyz
[[ ! $bar ]] || echo Test failed
[[ ! "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
bar=
[[ ! "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
[[ -n "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
[[ -z "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
bar=xyz
[[ -n "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
[[ -z "$bar" ]] || echo Test failed
bar=
[[ -n $bar ]] || echo Test failed
[[ -z $bar ]] || echo Test failed
bar=xyz
[[ -n $bar ]] || echo Test failed
[[ -z $bar ]] || echo Test failed
set +x  # Unnecessary if you save this in a script file and don't dot (source) it
```

It will (probably) help you understand what's going on.  The output is quite verbose, though.

Answer (score 2):

`if` tests the results of commands and can't directly test the values of variables. In this case you're using it in conjunction with the `test`/`[` command, which is an ordinary command and can be used anywhere.

```
[ -f ./foo.txt ] && echo "foo.txt exists"
```

or equivalently

```
test -f ./foo.txt && echo "foo.txt exists"
```

both test whether a file exists at the path `./foo.txt`.

Depending on what you mean by "true", you can use the `test` or `[` shell builtin to determine whether a variable is equal to another, and for some other functions like testing whether a directory or file exists.

You can use `if [ -z "$variable" ]; then ...; fi` to check whether a variable is the empty string.

If you want to check whether the variable is set at all, even to an empty value, you can use parameter expansion `[ -z "${var+x}" ]`. It only evaluates to `true` (meaning has exit status zero) when `var` is undefined.

If you want to compare a variable against a fixed string you can use `[ "$var" = "some-string" ]` or use `case` e.g.

```
case "$var" in
   some-string)
     dostuff
   ;;
esac
```

Note that you can negate that the result of `test`/`[` using `!`.

```
if ! [ -z "$var" ]; then
    do-something
fi
```

Does negate the condition.

However, `!` is also valid as an argument to `test`/`[`

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ]; then
    do-something
fi
```

means the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. I have a question about " It doesn't make sense as an argument to test or [." I do see "if [ ! -f regularfile ]; then" working  . Is it because -f operator ?

Comment: @nathan: `!` is perfectly valid inside `[ … ]` / `[[ … ]]` / as a `test` operand in general. You just need to understand how its operand is evaluated:
`$bar` isn't evaluated the way you expect: it is a _string_, and since it is a _nonempty_ string - irrespective of its _content_ -  it is considered "true"

Comment: @nathan, I was wrong about that. `!` is a valid argument of the `test` command. `test "$somestring"` will exit 0 if and only if `"$somestring"` expands to a non-empty string. `test ! "$something"` inverts this. That being said, it is more typical to use `test -z "$something"` or `test -n "$something"` to test for emptiness because this handles the edge case where `$something` is a weird value like `-z`.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Thanks very much.