# Negate a boolean variable and assign it to a new variable

Tags: bash

In a Bash script, I'd like to define a boolean variable `y` to store the negated value of another boolean variable `x`. The following script,

```
#!/bin/bash

x=true
y=$(( ! "${x}" ))
echo "${y}"
```

sets variable `y` to 1. How can I change `y` so it evaluates to `false` instead?

Comment: `y=$(case "$x" in true ) echo false ;; * ) echo "Unknown Value for x=$x" 1>&2 ; echo "nonesuch" ;; esac)` ??

Comment: This question/answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204576/exclamation-mark-to-test-variable-is-true-or-not-in-bash-shell/41205067#41205067

Comment: You do understand what `true ; echo $?` means? If you want to use return values `0` and `not 0`, you'll need to translate from the number to the text that you want. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Bash does not have the concept of boolean values for variables. The values of its variables are always strings. They can be handled as numbers in some contexts but that's all it can do.

You can use `1` and `0` instead or you can compare them (with `=` or `==`) as strings with `true` and `false` and pretend they are boolean. The code will be more readable but they are still strings :-)

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused, because `x=abc` (without quotes) is not allowed but `x=true` is. Does Bash internally convert "boolean" values to their string representation always before storing them?

Comment: @Ali No, it does not. Both `true` and `false` are regular strings.

Comment: .What do you mean` x=abc` is not allowed? In bash and every shell I know about, such an assignment is the most basic of operations. `x=abc; echo  $x` should produce `abc`, and `echo $?` returns `0`, indicating that that command executed successfully.  What where you looking for? I'm only guessing here, but don't try to implement syntax you found handy in another language in your shell code. It will confuse future maintainers, etc. Good luck.