# Extract missing digits in a sequence

Tags: bash, shell

I extracted some digits from files using `grep`, assuming they are `1 2 3 5 6 11 18`. To get the missings ones in `1..20`, I put them into files and compare using `comm`.

```
a='1 2 3 5 6 11 18'
printf '%d\n' $a | sort -u > 111
printf '%d\n' {1..20} | sort -u > 222
comm 111 222
rm 111 222
```

which outputs

```
    1
10
    11
12
13
14
15
16
17
    18
19
    2
20
    3
4
    5
    6
7
8
9
```

Is there more convenient way without saving to files?

Comment: [Process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) : `comm <(printf '%d\n' $a | sort -u) <(printf '%d\n' {1..20})` Side note: for second case `{1..20}`, you don't need sort; they are already sorted.

Comment: ^^ Having said that, a pure bash variant can be written easily: `a='1 2 3 5 6 11 18'; for x in $a; do t[$x]=1; done; for((x=1;x<=20;x++)); do ((t[i])) || echo $i; done`

Comment: Thanks @anishsane . But the 2nd one outputs null lines. The 1st one needs `sort`. `1 2 3 4 ... 10 ...20` is not deemed as sorted, but `1 10 11 ... 2 20 3 ...` does.

Comment: ^^ My bad... for the first one, use `sort -un` instead of just `sort -u`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the numbers from 1 though 20, and then use a regex to compare each number against `a`:

```
a='1 2 3 5 6 11 18'
for i in {1..20}; do
  re="\\b$i\\b"
  [[ "$a" =~ $re ]] || echo "$i"
done
```

The regex is quite simple: `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), and `$i`  gets expanded to 1, 2, ..., 20

The above will print all numbers that are not in `a`.

Comment: Hi @andlrc it works but I have no idea why two backslashes not just one? and why `[[ "$a" =~ "\\b$i\\b" ]] || echo "$i"` doesn't work

Comment: In theory `"\b"` should work but since backslash is an escape character we need to escape it: `\\b` -> `\b`, or put it in single quotes: `'\b'"$i"'\b'`. For why `[[ "$a" =~ "\\b$i\\b" ]]` doesn't work: It seems to be a bug in bash, there is an explanation here: [does bash support word boundary regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696899/887539)