# How to check if string exists in bash variable

Tags: string, bash, variables

I have a variable $FOO with values `one two three`.

```
echo $FOO
one two three
```

Is there a way in bash to check if `two` exists and exactly matches one of the values of $FOO

I can do this

```
if [[ "two" =~ ^(one|two|three)$ ]]; then
    echo "two is in the list"
else
    echo "two is not in the list"
fi
```

And it works, but I'd like to check using the actual variable $FOO and not `(one|two|three)$`

Is this possible?

Comment: define *`exactly matches`*; do you mean it has to match a 'word', eg, you would *not* get a match if `FOO='one 1two3 three'`?

Comment: You can use [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792702/does-bash-support-word-boundary-regular-expressions), or perhaps like `if [[  "$FOO" =~ (^| )two($| ) ]]; then`

Comment: Yes. No partial matches. So `twoo` or `two1` should not match. Only `two`

Answer (score 2):

If the items in `$FOO` are guaranteed to be separated by spaces, you can use this:

```
if [[ " $FOO " = *" $TWO "* ]]; then
    ...
```

Note that this reverses the roles of `$FOO` and `$TWO` from what you might expect; it treats `$FOO` as the string to check against a pattern, and the pattern is essentially "something that contains `$TWO`". It also adds explicit spaces to `$TWO` to make sure it matches only full items, and similarly adds spaces around `$FOO` so that'll match the first and last items in it.

If the delimiters in `$FOO` might be tabs or other space-like characters, you can use this more complex pattern:

```
if [[ " $FOO " = *[[:space:]]"$TWO"[[:space:]]* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to do it below

```
FOO='one two three'
TWO='two'
if [[ "$FOO" == *"$TWO"* ]]; then
  echo "two is in the list"
fi
```

wildcard aka * is a symbol used to represent zero, one or more characters.

Comment: this will also match for `FOO='one 1two3 three`

Comment: or `FOO='flatworm'`

Answer (score 0):

Using an array

```
$ FOO=(one two three)
$ n=0;while [[ $n -lt ${#FOO} ]]; do  [[ "${FOO[$n]}" == "two" ]] && echo "two is in the list"; n=$(( $n + 1 )); done
two is in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct pattern with :

```
foo=(one two three)
pattern="^($(IFS="|"; echo "${foo[*]}"))\$"

if  [[ two =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "two is in the list"
else
    echo "two is not in the list"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that nobody posted `case`. It's the simplest and most portable. Notice the added spaces around `$FOO`.

```
case " $FOO " in
*" two "*) echo two is in the list; ;;
*) echo two is not in the list; ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
FOO="one two three"

foo=( $FOO )

if [[ "${foo[*]}" =~ ' two ' ]]
then
    echo "two is in the list"
else
    echo "two is not in the list"
fi
```

which will work for the simple cases (i.e. no spaces in the values)

Comment: This won't match if `two` begins or ends the list. There's also no point in creating an array only to create a new string from the array immediately.

Answer (score -1):

This should also work for you.

```
FOO='one two three'
TWO='two'
if [[ "$FOO" =~ "$TWO"( |$) ]]
then
  echo "two is in the list"
else
    echo "two is not in the list"
fi
```

This will give an exact pattern match.

Comment: This would also match something like `FOO=twoling`.