# How do I check if variable is an array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a loop over variable names and I need to check if content of a variable is an array or not:

```
for varname in AA BB CC; do
  local val
  if [ "$varname" is array ]; then # how can I perform this test?
    echo do something with an array
  else
    echo do something with a "'normal'" variable
  fi
done
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Related and worth reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67898/using-the-not-equal-operator-for-string-comparison

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [this wiki page](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Detect_if_variable_is_an_array), you can use this command:

```
declare -p variable-name 2> /dev/null | grep -q '^declare \-a'
```

Comment: I added the `^` to the pattern to avoid the false positive on `variable-name='declare -a'` mentioned in the examples.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. As an excuse for not googling, I did find the link you mention, but I am forbidden to view it. man bash has all of it there, though, but I didn't think about looking for in under 'declare'... Thanks!

Comment: a faster alternative: `str="\`declare -p astr 2>/dev/null\`";if [[ "${str:0:10}" == 'declare -a' ]];then echo array;fi` I wonder if there is anything faster?

Comment: Google is my friend, that's why he took me here. (It's also because he's friend of SO.)

Comment: commenting on multiple answers: if you update your grep to also check for 'typeset' instead of just 'declare', this will be more portable.

Comment: @Sparr you can suggest an edit to an existing answer or post your own. Notably, none of the existing answers explain why this works, so explaining that (and why it's necessary to check for `typeset` too) would be a very helpful addition.

Comment: I found that if I do `declare -A x ; declare -p x` I'm told `bash: declare: x: not found`. I have to actually _use_ the array before it's recognised as such: `declare -A x ; x[_]= ; unset x[_] ; declare -p x` returns `declare -A x='()'`.  I don't know if this is expected behaviour, but thought it worth mentioning!  (This is only for uninitialised arrays, by the way.  If I initialise it to empty - `declare -A x='()'` - it works as expected.)

Comment: Downvoted because of the "Google/RTFM it" style remarks, which really are at odds with the very spirit of what SO/SE is about.

Comment: This does not work for namerefs. `declare -n a; b=( c d e ); a=b; declare -p a; echo ${a[2]}` shows
    `declare -n a="b"; e`. edit: Ah, see other answer.

Answer (score 49):

To avoid a call to grep, you could use:

```
if [[ "$(declare -p variable_name)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    echo array
else
    echo no array
fi
```

Comment: commenting on multiple answers: if you update your regex to also check for 'typeset' instead of just 'declare', this will be more portable.

Comment: None of these answers handle empty arrays correctly. Declare gives a 'bash: declare: var: not found' error, despite the fact that the variable appears when you run 'declare -ap'. So a solution that includes empty variables might have to grep the output of 'declare -ap'.

Comment: @Sparr, sure, `typeset` is available in other shells, but that doesn't mean the output will be identical.

Comment: This currently looks for the string **anywhere** in the output from `declare -p` -- so it would match a string containing the literal contents `declare -a` somewhere within.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think changing the regex to `^declare -a variable_name($|=)` would solve that: `pattern="^declare -a variable_name($|=)"; if [[ "$(declare -p variable_name)" =~ $pattern ]];then ...`. Here `^` anchors `declare` to the start of the line, while `($|=)` causes it to match only if the declaration is followed by a value assignment or end of line. End of line is to match the output if declared but not assigned in bash 4.4.12 (although not in bash 3.2.57, but this patterns works there too because it's output is `=()` in that case).

Comment: P.S. I first assigned the pattern to a variable because quoting regex patterns [doesn't work in newer versions of bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218217/741217) (although the example in Reuben W's answer does work)

Comment: To also make this pattern work for associative arrays, use this pattern instead: `^declare -(a|A) variable_name($|=)`

Comment: @RolfW., if the output is multi-line, does `^` match at the beginning of *any* line, or only the first?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd say at the beginning of the first; I couldn't find a reference easily, but I'm pretty sure the `=~` operator doesn't support multi-line mode. In this case I don't think it matters though, because `declare -p variable_name` will return only that one item if it was declared, or `declare: variable_name: not found` otherwise. In case the value of the variable contains a line that also matches this pattern, it would still evaluate to `echo array` in the example above.

Comment: @RolfW. @CharlesDuffy the regular expression will also need to account for the other flags that could appear in the declaration, e.g. `r` (read-only) and `x` (exported) could also appear in the declaration: `declare -arx myArray=...`.

Comment: I'd add a ` 2>/dev/null` to the subshell to avoid error messages when the variable is not declared at all.

Comment: Dear @Reuben W, please, if you ever return to StackOverflow, recheck the edit queue... The regex requires an attention indeed as also mentioned in the comments to the answer...

Answer (score 25):

Since bash 4.3 it is not that easy anymore.

With "declare -n" you can add a reference to another variable and you can do this over and over again. As if this was not complicated enough, with "declare -p", you do not get the type or the original variable.

Example:

```
$ declare -a test=( a b c d e)
$ declare -n mytest=test
$ declare -n newtest=mytest
$ declare -p newtest
declare -n newtest="mytest"
$ declare -p mytest
declare -n mytest="test"
```

Therefore you have to loop through all the references. In bash-only this would look like this:

```
vartype() {
    local var=$( declare -p $1 )
    local reg='^declare -n [^=]+=\"([^\"]+)\"$'
    while [[ $var =~ $reg ]]; do
            var=$( declare -p ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} )
    done

    case "${var#declare -}" in
    a*)
            echo "ARRAY"
            ;;
    A*)
            echo "HASH"
            ;;
    i*)
            echo "INT"
            ;;
    x*)
            echo "EXPORT"
            ;;
    *)
            echo "OTHER"
            ;;
    esac
}
```

With the above example:

```
$ vartype newtest
ARRAY
```

To check for array, you can modify the code or use it with grep:

```
vartype $varname | grep -q "ARRAY"
```

Comment: For a non-`declare`d variable, catch/ignore the error message by changing first line to `local var=$( declare -p $1 2>/dev/null )`.

Comment: I found that using `declare -p ${!theVar}` seemed to do the trick, as in `isRefArray () { local -n refToCheck=$1; testResult="$(declare -p ${!refToCheck})"; [[ $testResult =~ "declare -a" ]];}`

Comment: I believe the `grep` example should be replaced with anything Bash-only considering the initial Bash regex processing, too. Still awesome Grep is a third-party. Nevertheless, my... dear... This a genius and so simply great approach! Thank you very much! Bellissimo! ✨

Answer (score 7):

I started with Reuben's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27254437/1255289) above. I implemented a few of the comments and some of my own improvements and came out with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_test() {
    # no argument passed
    [[ $# -ne 1 ]] && echo 'Supply a variable name as an argument'>&2 && return 2
    local var=$1
    # use a variable to avoid having to escape spaces
    local regex="^declare -[aA] ${var}(=|$)"
    [[ $(declare -p "$var" 2> /dev/null) =~ $regex ]] && return 0
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
foo=(lorem ipsum dolor)
bar="declare -a tricky"
declare -A baz

array_test foo && echo "it's an array"
array_test bar && echo "it's an array"
# properly detects empty arrays
array_test baz && echo "it's an array"
# won't throw errors on undeclared variables
array_test foobarbaz && echo "it's an array"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
is_array() {
  local variable_name=$1
  [[ "$(declare -p $variable_name)" =~ "declare -a" ]]
}

is_array BASH_VERSINFO && echo BASH_VERSINFO is an array
```

---

```
is_array() {
    local variable_name=$1
    [[ "$(declare -p $variable_name 2>/dev/null)" =~ "declare -a" ]]
}
```

Comment: Any additional explanation would help improve your answer.

Comment: commenting on multiple answers: if you update your regex to also check for 'typeset' instead of just 'declare', this will be more portable.

Comment: @Sparr, I disagree that it will be more portable in practice, because a shell that doesn't support `declare -p` won't have `declare -a` in the output of `typeset`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't remember the scenario in which this was relevant to me. Based on the time of my comment, I suspect I was using OSX at the time.

Comment: OSX does come with (real David Korn) ksh93, which uses `typeset` rather than `declare`, so that *does* make sense -- but one would still need to adjust the regex and test it in both places.

Comment: zsh also appears to reply with typeset too.

Answer (score 1):

Another Way:

*Example, create an Array:*

```
Variable=(The Quick Brown Fox...)
```

*Test the Variable:*

```
if [ "${#Variable[@]}" -gt "1" ] ;
 then echo "Variable is an Array"; 
else echo "Variable is NOT an Array" ; 
fi
```

Comment: This fails when the array is of length 1 or empty, but still an array.

Comment: In practice, it is rarely to happen that an Array has only 1 content. There is actually no difference between an ordinary variable and an array with only 1 index value.

Example:

Var=hello

echo ${Var}
hello

echo ${Var[0]}
hello

# lets add another index value
Var[1]=h3ll0

echo ${Var}
hello

echo ${Var[0]}
hello

echo ${Var[1]}
h3ll0

echo ${Var[0]}
hello

echo $Var
hello

As you can see there is no difference. But I get your point.

Comment: this imperfect answer has the benefit of not requiring a fork+exec to get the answer

Comment: @Josef, there is actually a difference between single element array and ordinary variable: "set -u; a=(1);unset a[0];echo ${#a[@];b=1;unset b[0];echo ${#b[@]}. If I use your test to verify if a var is an array, I will just get an error with this code.

Answer (score 1):

**I usually use the following functions to check for arrays/dicts (e.g. to verify a sourced configuration):**

```
# Check if variable is an array [$1: variable name]
function is_array() {
    [[ "$(declare -p -- "$1")" == "declare -a "* ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

# Check if variable is a dict [$1: variable name]
function is_dict() {
    [[ "$(declare -p -- "$1")" == "declare -A "* ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
```

I don't see any benefit in using regular expressions here, simple string matching is quite sufficient.

As others already pointed out, this approach will NOT work for namerefs and/or additional flags like readonly (which is sufficient in my experience -> KISS).

**NOTE:** `&& return 0 || return 1` may actually be omitted, I just added that to make the code self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it, it checks that the array indexes don't match "" or "0"

It should be cheap for small arrays and non-arrays.

It works by testing for any non-zero character in the array indexes

```
is_array() {
  eval [[ "\"\${!$1[*]}\"" =~ "[1-9]" ]]
}

an_array=(1 2 3)
wierd_array[4]=3
non_array="Joe"
unset non_exist

is_array an_array && echo pass || echo fail
is_array wierd_array && echo pass || echo fail
is_array non_array && echo fail || echo pass
is_array non_exist && echo fail || echo pass
```

output should be

```
pass
pass
pass
pass
```

Answer (score 0):

miken32's improvement actually causes a regression. The following

```
a=()
export a
readonly a
declare -p a
```

prints

```
declare -arx a=()
```

which would match if you were just checking for `declare -a` as a substring, but would fail with miken's more complicated regex. I recommend just using

```
isArray() {
  # why do we need a regex again?
  [[ $(declare -p "$1") == 'declare -'[aA]* ]]
}
```

For the ksh folks, it's probably `[[ $(declare -p $1) ~= '^(declare|typeset) -[aA]'` or `[[ $(declare -p $1) == @(declare|typeset)\ -[aA]`.

---

No, I don't think not throwing an error on undeclared is a good idea. And no, I have no idea why miken checks the variable name on declare output.