# Regex and quoted strings

Tags: regex, bash

Here is a variable called "target"

```
$ echo $_target
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

This regex test succeeds...

```
$ if [[ $_target =~ "x86_64" ]]; then echo "match"; fi
match
```

But it doesn't test to see if the expression is at the beginning of the line. Let me add the anchor tag to the regex:

```
$ if [[ $_target =~ "^x86_64" ]]; then echo "match"; fi
$
```

The line above doesn't indicate a match. Weird.

However, if I take off the quotes around the regular expression, all is good

```
$ if [[ $_target =~ ^x86_64 ]]; then echo "match"; fi
match
```

Why do the quotes influence the regular expression test? What am I missing in my understanding to be surprised that the second test above fails to match?

Comment: possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the right side of the =~ operator in quotes, as this will mean a string, and not a regex. ([source](http://unixdog.com/?p=94)