# Bash regex not capturing

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a string which includes the text:

```
...,"names":"exampleName",...
```

I have the following if statement that checks if the regex pattern matches the string:

```
if [[ $string =~ names\":\"(\w+)\" ]]; then
      echo "Matches"
fi
```

The problem is the echo statement never get's executed, which essentially means that the regex didn't match.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Because it should match...

Cheers.

Comment: How is $string assigned?

Comment: $string is assigned the output of: string=$(curl ...)

Answer (score 1):

It's a quoting issue, see e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

Try:

```
$ string='...,"names":"exampleName",...'

$ re='names":"(\w+)"'

$ if [[ $string =~ $re ]]; then echo match; fi
match
```

Comment: Escaped quotes don't trigger string matching. His problem is likely due to the `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be that you are using an unsupported character class identifier.  As per reference 1 below, it appears that bash uses the POSIX character classes rather than the slash-escaped character classes used in vi and other places.

Rather than using `\w` you should use `[[:alnum:]_]` (alphanumerics plus the underscore).  I'd say to use `[[:word:]]`, but apparently not all versions of bash support that (as mine doesn't).

A version of your code modified appropriately would look like this:

```
string='...,"names":"exampleName",...'

if [[ $string =~ names\":\"([[:alnum:]_]+)\" ]]; then
  echo "Matches"
fi
```

**References:**

1. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html
2. http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if [[ $string =~ names\":\"[[:alnum:]_]+\" ]]; then
```