# Copying The Name Of One File To Another In Bash With Wild Cards

Tags: bash, file, wildcard, renaming

How can I copy the name of *.mkv to poster.jpg in bash using wild cards.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO... what did you try? how did it fail? give examples... read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Do you just want `cp *.mkv poster.jpg` (assuming that only one file will match)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match to files with `*.mkv` in the name, and for each file named `<foo>.mkv`, you want to create a `foo.jpg`, you can use regular expressions with parentheses around the parts of the regular expression you want to match, and then use `${BASH_REMATCH[n]}` to access the `n'th` matched part of the regular expression and reuse it elsewhere. There's an example here: [bash regex match string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/bash-regex-match-string).

If you're trying to do something completely different from what I just described, it would probably be a good idea to make your question clearer.