# What's wrong with this bash regex comparison?

Tags: regex, bash

I saw in [bash regex match string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/bash-regex-match-string) that I should compare regexes with =~.

Tried the following:

```
if [[ "____[9 / 101] Linking" =~ "[0-9]*" ]]; then echo "YES"; fi
```

And nothing is printed...

Tried without the quotes:

```
if [[ "____[9 / 101] Linking" =~ [0-9]* ]]; then echo "YES"; fi
```

And it works fine. But what to do if my regex contains white spaces (quotes required)?

Comment: **note** `[0-9]*` matches *zero or more occurrences* so it will always be true. Use `[0-9][0-9]*` to match *one or more* digits.

Comment: If you enclose the right part of `=~` in quotation marks, `=~` works like `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precede the whitespace with a `\`:

```
if [[ "____[9 / 101] Linking" =~ [0-9]*\ /\ [0-9]* ]]; then echo "YES"; fi
```

Comment: Accepted for the fastest working solution.

Answer (score 3):

Put your regex in a variable.  You are free to use quotes when defining the variable:

```
$ re="[0-9]*"  ; [[ "____[9 / 101] Linking" =~ $re ]] && echo "YES"
YES
$ re="9 /"  ; [[ "____[9 / 101] Linking" =~ $re ]] && echo "YES"
YES
```

Since the reference to `$re` inside `[[...]]` is unquoted, the value of `$re` is treated as a regex.  Anything on the right-side of `=~` that is quoted, however, will be treated as a literal string.

#### Notes

In regular expressions, as opposed to globs, `*` means *zero* or more of the preceding.  Thus `[0-9]*` is considered a match even if **zero** characters are matching:

```
$ re="[0-9]*"  ; [[ "____[a / bcd] Linking" =~ $re ]] && echo "YES"
YES
$ re="[0-9]"  ; [[ "____[a / bcd] Linking" =~ $re ]] && echo "YES"
$
```

If you want to match one or more digits, use `[0-9]+`.