# Bash string comparision

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Please help.

I'm trying to compare string1 against string2 in a Bash script.

I can do the easy bit of:-

```
if [[ $string1 == $string2 ]]
then    
    yippee    
fi
```

What I'm having trouble with is the syntax for when

```
"the$string1" == $string2  or "a$string1" == $string2
```

or

```
 $string1 == the$string2 or $string1 == a$string2
```

I assume it's something like:-

```
if [[ $string1 == $string2 || "(a|the)$string1" == $string2 || $string1 == "(a|the)$string2" ]]
```

But it's not and I cannot seem to find the answer. (I'm obviously asking the wrong question!)

Thanks for any help.

PS I'd rather not use any external progs such as awk etc.

Comment: Can you provide some concrete examples of comparisons that should be considered equal and not equal? Do you just want to compare the two strings ignoring any leading `a` or `the`?

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441521/bash-regex-operator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709962/regex-matching-in-a-bash-if-statement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/how-can-i-match-a-string-with-a-regex-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```sh
if [[ $string1 == *"$string2"* ]]; then
    echo "string1 contains string2"

elif [[ $string2 == *"$string1"* ]]; then
    echo "string2 contains string1"
fi
```

Within `[[...]]` the `==` operator is a *pattern matching* operator.

Ref: [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

---

For specifically an optional "a" or "the" prefix:

```sh
[[ $string1 == ?(a|the)"$string2" || $string2 == ?(a|the)"$string1" ]]
```

That uses bash's extended patterns, see [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: Note that the variable on the right-hand side is quoted: that is to treat it as literal text, in case the variable's contents contain shell globbing characters.