# Shell, compare two script with wildcard

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, wildcard, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two "almost" identical strings in a shell script.
They are similar except for one character (A-Z).
In the example below I want the code to return true for all cases of the string from
`1-2-3-A-5-6-` to `1-2-3-Z-5-6-`

Currently my code returns false.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMPLATE='1-2-3-*-5-6-'
CASE='1-2-3-A-5-6-'
if [[ "$TEMPLATE" == "$CASE" ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
else
  echo "NO, improve!"
fi
```

Comment: `case "$CASE" in $TEMPLATE) echo ok;; *) echo no;; esac`

Comment: Accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/how-can-i-match-a-string-with-a-regex-in-bash may be useful.

Comment: Simply `[[ $CASE = $TEMPLATE ]]` (in `bash`). The order of the operands of the `=` (or `==`) operator is significant. But use `?` (for a single character) instead of `*` in template.

Comment: To expand on that, in `[[ ... ]]`, the right-hand side is subject to shell pattern matching *unless quoted*.

Comment: @jhnc It's better to use `[A-Z]` or at least `?` instead of `*` if the difference should be *one character*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `1-2-3-*-5-6-` is a *glob*.

This pattern language is described in the **Pattern Matching** section of the bash manual, and available to both the `[[ == ]]` test you're trying to use (manual quoted below), and the `case` version mentioned in a comment.

> [[ expression ]]

> ... When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string **to the right of the operator** is considered a pattern and matched according to
> the  rules
> described  below  under Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled.  The `=` operator is equivalent to
> `==`.  If the nocase‐
> match shell option is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.

> ... Any part of the pattern may be **quoted to force the
> quoted portion to be matched as a string**.

There are only two constraints:

1. you can't quote the pattern if you want it to be matched as a pattern rather than a literal string

   (see the last quoted paragraph)
2. the pattern must go on the right hand side of the operator

   (first paragraph)

So your code will work fine as

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMPLATE='1-2-3-*-5-6-'
CASE='1-2-3-A-5-6-'
if [[ $CASE == $TEMPLATE ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
else
  echo "NO, improve!"
fi
```

---

NB. Part of the reason for using the built-in `[[ ]]` conditions instead of the old `[ ]` ones is specifically that

> Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the `[[` and `]];`

so you don't generally need to quote variables (and in this particular case, *must not* quote at least one of them).

Comment: @JoachimSpange, what happen to the `[A-Z]` pattern match?

Comment: That would also work, but the immediate problem was getting pattern matching behaviour in the first place, not the pattern itself.

Comment: @Useless @Jetchisel Is using `?` over `*` since it is just one character?

Comment: @Useless @Jetchisel I deleted my comment, the code I wrote in that comment was plain wrong. I meant that this works: 
`#!/bin/bash
TEMPLATE='1-2-3-?-5-6-'
CASE='1-2-3-B-5-6-'

if [[ $CASE == $TEMPLATE ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
else
  echo "NO, improve!"
fi
` Using `[A-Z]` instead of `?` works of course too and is a more precise for my use-case

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMPLATE='1-2-3-*-5-6-'
CASE='1-2-3-A-5-6-'
if [[ "$CASE" == ${TEMPLATE/\*/[A-Z]} ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
else
  echo "NO, improve!"
fi
```

---

Or you could add the glob/pattern `[A-Z]` directly at the assignment instead of the glob `*`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMPLATE='1-2-3-[A-Z]-5-6-'
CASE='1-2-3-E-5-6-'
if [[ "$CASE" == $TEMPLATE ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
else
  echo "NO, improve!"
fi
```

---

The accepted answer already explained the immediate error/problem with the OP's code. Just want to add a small snippet from `set -x` to support as to why you don't need to quote the rhs Right Hand Side of the `=` or `==` if the intention is to do a pattern matching.

```
+ TEMPLATE='1-2-3-[A-Z]-5-6-'
+ CASE=1-2-3-T-5-6-
+ [[ 1-2-3-T-5-6- == \1\-\2\-\3\-\[\A\-\Z\]\-\5\-\6\- ]]
+ echo 'NO, improve!'
NO, improve!
```

Quoting the RHS of the `==` or `=` or even `=~` operator will make it a literal string not a pattern/glob/regex, since every string has a leading `\`, and `\` is a form of quoting/escaping from the shell. What ever special meaning of a sting from the shell is now gone after it was escaped/quoted.

Comment: The key here is to NOT quote the right-hand operand of `==` so that it is handled as a pattern not as a literal string.