# Parsing OPTARG inside case with regular expression and [[ ]]'s

Tags: regex, bash, getopts

So, I'm setting up a bash script and want to parse arguments to certain flags using getopts. For a minimal example, consider the a script which has a flag, -M, and it takes y or n as an argument. If I use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# minimalExample.sh

while getopts "M:" OPTION;
do
case ${OPTION} in
        M)  
            RMPI=${OPTARG}
            if ! [[ "$RMPI" =~ "^[yn]$" ]]
            then
                echo "-M must be followed by either y or n."
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
esac
done
```

I get the following:

```
$ ./minimalExample.sh -M y
-M must be followed by either y or n.
FAIL: 1
```

However, if I use the following code instead

```
#!/bin/bash

# minimalExample2.sh

while getopts "M:" OPTION;
do
case ${OPTION} in
        M)  
            RMPI=${OPTARG}
            if [ -z $(echo $RMPI | grep -E "^[yn]$") ]
            then
                echo "-M must be followed by either y or n."
                exit 1
                            else
                                    echo "good"
            fi
            ;;
esac
done
```

I get:

```
$ ./minimalExample2.sh -M y
good
```

Why doesn't `minimalExample.sh` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoting regexp in this context forces a string comparison.

change to

```
if ! [[ "$RMPI" =~ ^[yn]$ ]]
```

check following post for more details,

[bash regex with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need regex here at all? `-M y` is not the same as `-M n`, is it? So you definitely will use some statement (`case` or `if`) to distinguish one from another.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "M:" OPTION; do
    case ${OPTION} in
            M)  
                case ${OPTARG} in
                    y) 
                        # do what must be done if -M y
                        ;;
                    n) 
                        # do what must be done if -M n 
                        ;;
                    *) 
                        echo >&2 "-M must be followed by either y or n."
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                ;;
    esac
done
```

Please note `>&2` – error messages should be output to `STDERR`, not to `STDOUT`.

Comment: Perhaps because at this point in the code, he is only validating the value of `RMPI`, and the specific value of `y` or `n` is not used until later.

Comment: @chepner is entirely correct. The case control in the beginning of my script is more for argument validation than anything else.