# What does the =~ operator do?

Tags: bash

I have come across this operator `=~` and couldn't figure it out on what it does. Could someone with bash knowledge kindly help me out?

Comment: In what context did you find that operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes

Comment: Have you tried searching for it in the [bash documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)?

Answer (score 2):

`man bash`

`/=~`

> An  additional  binary  operator,  =~,  is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an
>                 extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value is 0 if the string matches the  pattern,  and  1  otherwise.   If  the  regular
>                 expression  is  syntactically  incorrect,  the  conditional expression's return value is 2.  If the shell option nocasematch is enabled, the match is performed without
>                 regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions within  the  regular  expression  are  saved  in  the  array  variable
>                 BASH_REMATCH.   The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element of BASH_REMATCH with index n
>                 is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

In `~` is saved your home directory (for example: `/home/username`) and `=` is assignment operator.

If you run this code in bash:

```
x=~       # variable x will hold string value /home/your_username
echo $x   # print variable x via echo command
```

it will print something like: `/home/your_username`

Comment: True, but not at all likely to be what the OP is asking about. Bash does have an `=~` operator; see the other answer.