# RE matching operator not working in this script

Tags: bash

Strange enough, `[[ 111-11-1111 =~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ]]` just yield success on command line.

But this script cannot yield the same when I `bash re.sh 111-11-1111`

```
#!/bin/bash
# re.sh

input=$1


if [[ "$input" =~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ]]
#                 ^ NOTE: Quoting not necessary, as of version 3.2 of Bash.
# NNN-NN-NNNN (where each N is a digit).
then
  echo "Social Security number."
  # Process SSN.
else
  echo "Not a Social Security number!"
  # Or, ask for corrected input.
fi
```

why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash regex with quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

Comment: I am using bash 4.3 and it only works when I leave out the second pair of quotes in the if: `if [[ "$input" =~  [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]` . `bash -x re.sh` reveals some strange things going with qoutes present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you should remove the quotes on the regular expression if you're using `bash 3.2` or higher.  Also though, here's a shorter expression:

```
if [[ $input =~ ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$ ]]
```