# Simple regex matching produces wildly different results depending on shell version

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Long story short:

```
bash --version | head -n 1; [[ "abc" =~ "^a" ]] && echo Match || echo No match
```

Results on host 1:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
Match
```

Results on host 2:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
No match
```

What environment directives and/or configuration options should I check in order to produce consistent results?

For completion, please be advised they don't always fail to match all regular expressions. Slightly altering the regular expression (removing the "beginning of string" caret constraint) does produce consistent results:

```
bash --version | head -n 1; [[ "abc" =~ "a" ]] && echo Match || echo No match
```

Results on host 1:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
Match
```

Results on host 2:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Match
```

Comment: Regex should not be quoted. Use: `[[ "abc" =~ ^a ]] && echo Match || echo 'No match'`

Comment: [related : bash regex with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes), this seems to be a change between bash 3.1 and 3.2