# Escaping " in bash script regular expression

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to get the id value but cannot. I also tried escaping `"` with `\"`

```
text="Id": "d246ad6f48f7"
[[ "${text}" =~ (.*)": "(.*)" ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Comment: In the future please first search to see if you question has already been asked before. Does this answer your question? [bash regex with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the call `text="Id": "d246ad6f48f7"` returns an error `d246ad6f48f7: command not found`. You should call `text='"Id": "d246ad6f48f7"'` instead. But it is hard to match " in bash regex. I recommend using `sed` like this:

```sh
echo '"Id": "d246ad6f48f7"' | sed -E '{s/"(.*)": "(.*)"/\2/}'
d246ad6f48f7
```

Explanation for `sed`:

- `-E` extented Regular Expression
- `\2` second backreference