# Bash Regex if else

Tags: bash

In Bash I'm trying to check if a string is in the appropriate format.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_MSG="release/patch/JIRA-123"

[[ $COMMIT_MSG =~ 'release\/(major|minor|patch)\/[A-Z\d]+-\d+' ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

This is the regex I've used to match the string as `patch` could be either `major` or `minor` and `JIRA-123` is Jira Ticket ID but when trying it in the Bash regex it always returns `no`.

Comment: Use `[[ $COMMIT_MSG =~ release/(major|minor|patch)/[A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+ ]]` . Don't quote the regex and use `0-9` instead of `\d`.

Comment: Quoting the pattern makes bash treat it as a literal string, rather than regex syntax. Actually, to avoid inconsistencies between bash versions, it's best to store the pattern in a variable, then use that (unquoted) in the actual test. See ["bash regex with quotes?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218156/bash-regex-with-quotes) Also, `\d` probably isn't supported (especially inside a bracket expression).

Comment: Note that `condition && action1 || action2` in bash is not a ternary expression so be careful when treating it as one - as written you could get `no` output even if your regexp comparison succeeded. Whether or not you care probably depends on how likely you think it is that `echo "yes"` might fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash is a simplified version of regex called "[Extended Regular Expression](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)".  `\d` doesn't exist in it, so use `[0-9]` instead.

Additionally, you shouldn't quote the regex in the condition.

```
[[ $COMMIT_MSG =~ release/(major|minor|patch)/[A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+ ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```