# Bash regex: Do you have to escape a backtick with a character class?

Tags: regex, bash

I've found in a regex I have that if the string I'm testing has a backtick in it, I can only get it to match is if I escape the backtick while enclosed in brackets > **[\`]**. Regularly escaping the character like you would an asterisk **\*** does not work, nor does just keeping the backtick in brackets. In fact, the formatting of this post gets screwed up with these backticks.

What is it with backticks that causes such mayhem? I know they have a special function in bash, but matching them is much more complicated than other characters.

EDIT: @anubhava has an example that works, but I still see in my particular regex that the backtick MUST be escaped. Example below, the backtick is right before the capturing parentheses.

```
pattern="symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]][\`]([^[[:space:]]+)'"
```

This should match to some text like this:

```
z1.gz: symbolic link to `zip1.gz'
```

This is a simple `file` command return, but could apply to anything else.

Comment: The backtick is not special for regexp but it is special for shells. You don't have to escape it in the regexp but you have to escape it if the regexp is a string enclosed in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) (`"`) in a shell script. If it is not escaped, the shell thinks that it starts a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and complains that it cannot find where the substitution ends. Or, worse, if there is another unescaped backtick, it tries to run the text between them as a command.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #35 (if \[\[ $foo =~ 'some RE' \]\])](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D) and [bash regex with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218156/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well character backtick has a special meaning in sh/bash for command substitution.

However for using that in a regex you can avoid any escaping if you use single quotes to store regular expression in a variable. Consider this example:

```bash
re='^[a-z0-9`]+$'
[[ 'abc`12' =~ $re ]] && echo 'match' || echo 'nope'

match
```

---

**EDIT:**

```bash
re='symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]`[^[:space:]]+'
[[ "$(file some-file)" =~ $re ]] && echo 'match' || echo 'nope'

match
```

Comment: Yes, I found I have to keep the regex saved as a variable, first (I don't know why). I'm still wondering why yours works even though the backtick is not escaped. I HAVE to use the syntax in my question above for it to work in my regex.
pattern="symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]][\`]([^[[:space:]]+)'"

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and provide example code there otherwise it is not possible to read from comment

Comment: I can't get the comment to format. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I've found in a regex I have that if the string I'm testing has a backtick in it, I can only get it to match is if I escape the backtick while enclosed in brackets > **[\`]**. Regularly escaping the character like you would an asterisk **\*** does not work, nor does just keeping the backtick in brackets.

POSIX regexes have no such issues with backticks, but because of their significance to the shell, literal backticks in your shell commands do need to be quoted to prevent them from being interpreted as delimiting a command substitution.  Moreover, ***double quotes don't do that job***.  Like parameter references, command substitutions are still recognized within double-quoted regions.  You need single quotes or a backslash to escape a backtick.

Observe:

```
$ pattern="symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]][\`]([^[[:space:]]+)'"
$ echo "$pattern"
symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]][`]([^[[:space:]]+)'
```

There is no backslash in that pattern.  It was used merely to escape the backtick in the command to set variable `pattern`.  And that pattern works:

```bash
$ text="z1.gz: symbolic link to \`zip1.gz'"
$ echo "$text"
z1.gz: symbolic link to `zip1.gz'
$ [[ "$text" =~ $pattern ]] && echo matches
matches
```

But it also works without the square brackets:

```bash
$ pattern="symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]\`([^[[:space:]]+)'"
$ echo "$pattern"
symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]`([^[[:space:]]+)'
$ [[ "$text" =~ $pattern ]] && echo matches
matches
```

And of course, you can use single quotes to avoid escaping the backtick, but then you need to quote that trailing literal single quote differently.  For example:

```
$ pattern='symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]`([^[[:space:]]+)'\'
$ echo "$pattern"
symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]`([^[[:space:]]+)'
$ [[ "$text" =~ $pattern ]] && echo matches
matches
```

And you can express the pattern literally in the match expression:

```
$ [[ "$text" =~ \
     symbolic[[:space:]]link[[:space:]]to[[:space:]]\`([^[[:space:]]+)\' ]] && echo matches
matches
```

... though that's a bit unwieldy.

> What is it with backticks that causes such mayhem? I know they have a special function in bash, but matching them is much more complicated than other characters.

You dismiss backticks' significance to the shell too lightly, I think, while also inflating the complexity of matching them.  My best guess is that much of your difficulty arose from not appreciating that their special significance still applies inside double quotes -- which is intentional and needful to allow command substitutions to be protected from word splitting.